# What boundary is added when boundary condition is not sufficient?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, implementation-details

When insufficient boundary conditions are given to `NDSolve` for solving PDE, *usually* the warning `NDSolve::bcart` pops up:

```
sol = u /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
                      u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], 
                      Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E}, 
                   u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]];
```

> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: An insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution

However, `NDSolve` still gives an answer in this case:

```
Manipulate[Plot[sol[t, x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

I wonder what boundary has been introduced for this solution?

`sol` is changeless no matter how many times you rerun the code, so there exists a certain strategy, which I fail to find in the documentation. The only thing I know is that `NDSolve` doesn't use the value of the initial condition at the end point:

```
sol2 = u /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], 
             Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E, 
             u[t, 1] == Exp[-1]}, 
          u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]]

Manipulate[Plot[sol2[t, x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

or the derivative value of the initial condition at the end point:

```
sol3 = u /. 
  NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], 
             Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E, 
             Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1] == -2/E}, 
          u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]]

Manipulate[Plot[sol3[t, x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Well, I know the best countermeasure is to add the missing boundary condition, I'm just curious. Anyway, if the output with insufficient boundary condition is completely meaningless, why doesn't `NDSolve` simply stop calculating and return the input?

Finally, as [mentioned by Bru](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141364/1871), the warning `bcart` doesn't *always* pop up, for example:

```
sol = u /. NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
                    u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], 
                    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
                    Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E}, 
                   u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]];
```

---

## Update

I've partly found the answer, in short, `NDSolve` doesn't intentionally add any boundary condtion in this case, the solution we get is just a outgrowth of one-sided formula. Sadly I still don't know what's the equivalent boundary condition to this outgrowth. I tried to ask it in scicomp.SE, but the result is… not great. Please check the following post for more information:

[Why do I still obtain a unique solution with one-sided formula when b.c. isn't enough?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28033/5331)

---

## Remark

In the examples above, `TensorProductGrid` sub-method has been automatically chosen for spatial discretization, and `TensorProductGrid` is the only available method for spatial discretization in and before *v9*.

Since *v10*, `FiniteElement` method is implemented in `NDSolve`. Unlike `TensorProductGrid`, the b.c. added by `FiniteElement` is documented. As mentioned in the **Details** of `NeumannValue`:

> …not specifying a boundary condition at all is equivalent to specifying a Neumann 0 condition.

Notice `FiniteElement` method will only be triggered under certain condition. See the following post for more information:

[PDEs : automatic method choice : TensorProductGrid or FiniteElement?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/1871)

Answer (score 7):

You may try to fit a boundary condition, although it won't give you hints about the inner workings:

```
sol = u /. NDSolve[{ D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
                     u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2],
                     Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E},
                     u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]]

n = 30;
coefs = Table[c[i], {i, n}];
solMy = u /. NDSolve[{
     D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
     u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2],
     u[t, 1] == NonlinearModelFit[Table[{t, sol[t, 1]}, {t, 0, 2, .00005}], 
                              coefs.Array[t^# &, n] + Exp[-1], coefs, t]["BestFit"],
     Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -1] == 2/E},
    u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -1, 1}][[1]]

Plot3D[Abs[solMy[t, x] - sol[t, x]], {x, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You mixed up `-1` and `1` in your code, right?

Comment: @xzczd Yep, I tried both and ended up mixing them. I'll edit in a few minutes. Thanks for checking.

Comment: 千金市骨 :) Hope someone can answer this question one day.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that a possible answer is that the b.c. is simply the one that occurs. It is not of the form $w_b=const$ but of the time-dependant form $w_b=w_b(t)$. There may not be an analytic expression for $w_b(t)$ as it could be the solution of a differential equation that cannot be solved analytically.  So why don't check whether $w_b(t)$ is just the solution of the differential equation in your question?

I think this is also the answer to a question of mine. Check [this post.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188343/a-numerical-boundary-conditions-paradox)

Comment: "So why don't check… " The solution is valid of course. This can be easily checked with `Plot3D[D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] /. u -> sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1/2}, {x, -1, 1}(*,
  PlotRange -> All]*)`, one will see the error gets smaller when spatial grid gets denser (this can be adjusted with `{"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25(*adjust this*), "MinPoints" -> 25(*adjust this*), 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}`).

Comment: Then the problem is solved! The solution that occurs is characterised by time-dependent b.c. that is the numerical solution of the equation in question. It sounds reasonable. However if I am missing something let me know.

Comment: Indeed, this is an answer, but I should say it's a trivial one and my problem isn't solved with satisfaction. A fatal truth is, nobody has ever managed to figure out the physical meaning of this type of solution.

Comment: I think that it is neither trivial nor artificial. It is just a solution with its own b.c. like anyother solution. What kind of b.c.? Time dependent without analytical expression, solutions of the PDE system in question. Why should such a solution be termed trivial? Probably we should post a question concerning b.c. without explicit analytical expression. This would probably clarify our discussion

Comment: Well, I use the word _trivial_ because I think the explanation in your answer is something that, frankly speaking, anybody that has read through my question will immediately notice. And this has essentially been included in the answer posted by belisarius. However, what I'm concerned is something deeper. Can this b.c. been expressed in simpler, or analytic form? Does this solution own physical meaning in some cases? Why doesn't `NDSolve` simply stop calculating? These all remain unclear.