# Singularity while solving PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, physics

I have to solve a PDE (in the context of the functional renormalization group in physics). I have a function of two variables, $U(l,p)$. I know $U(0,p)=U_0(p)$ and then I have an equation (eq925) that gives me $\partial_l U(l,p)$. Here is the code

Definitions

```
eq925 = D[U[l, p], l] == d U[l, p] - (d - 2) p D[U[l, p], p] - k[d]/d (1/(1 + D[U[l, p], p] + 2 p D[U[l, p], {p, 2}]));
k[d_] := (2^(d - 1) π^(d/2) Gamma[d/2])
U0[p_] := u0/6 (p - p0)^2
u0v = 0.01;
p0v = 0.050459;
d = 3;
```

Attempt at solving

```
s2 = NDSolve[{eq925, U[0, p] == Evaluate[U0[p] /. {u0 -> u0v, p0 -> p0v}]},U[l, p], {l, 0, 1}, {p, -4, 4}]
```

Depending on the range of `p` in my `NDSolve` I get problems. If I only keep positive `p`, I get a reasonable solution, but if include (like I did in the previous line code) negative values of `p`, I get this error

> ```
> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of
>  3152.029270554484` at l = 0.0659979486053968` in the direction of independent variable 
>  p is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may 
>  be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed 
>  or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints 
>  method options. >>
> ```

I know I could have singularities in the denominator of `eq925`, but this should happen in my case for values around $p=-100$, which is far outside my range.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I get another warning, `NDSolve::bcart` -- why aren't you concerned with that one? Or don't you get the message?

Comment: So you're solving the equation on an infinite region?

Comment: This error message is quite common (unfortunately) when solving PDEs.  It can have many causes, the most common of which (in my experience) is a numerical instability.  Sometimes, increasing resolution helps, but often it makes things worse.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In OP's case it's mainly because of the absence of the boundary condition. BTW the behavior of `NDSolve` when boundary conditons aren't enough isn't fully understand so far, I used to [ask this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871) but didn't get a satisfied answer.

Comment: @xzczd  Agreed.  Too bad you did not get an answer to your question (+1).  I started out with my answer below, hoping to find some simple work-around but did not.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I do not have other boundary conditions because the physical theory I'm trying to solve gives me only this equation and the starting condition. I have the dependence of U on $l$, and I know what U is at $l=0$. I wouldn't know how to add another condition without changing the physics.
What is wierd is that I've taken this example from a book and they just plot the solution without any problem

Comment: @bnado  Is the book, or at least the problem, anywhere on the internet?  I assure you that the problem is not solvable without boundary conditions.

Comment: @bnado  How did you conclude, as you did in the question, that singularities in the equation only occur around `p = - 100` or smaller?  I would estimate that they would occur for around `p = -6` or smaller.  Also, have you considered transforming to Lagrangian coordinates?

Comment: Mine was an estmiate, since at l=0 the singularity is around p=-100. Anyway the book is Introduction to the Functional Renormalization Group by Kopietz et al, I'm trying to reproduce fig 9.1 or 9.2 using eq 9.25 or 9.27

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but may provide some helpful insight.  The code as written contains some unnecessary functions which slow the computation slightly and reduce clarity.  Instead, one could use

```
d = 3; u0v = .01; p0v = 0.050459;
k = (2^(d - 1) π^(d/2) Gamma[d/2]);
U0 = u0v/6 (p - p0v)^2;
eq925 = D[U[l, p], l] == d U[l, p] - (d - 2) p D[U[l, p], p] - 
    k/d (1/(1 + D[U[l, p], p] + 2 p D[U[l, p], {p, 2}]));

s2 = First@NDSolve[{eq925, U[0, p] == U0}, U[l, p], {l, 0, 1}, {p, -1.5, 4}, 
    MaxSteps -> 100000]
```

`-1.5` is used as the lower boundary for `p`, because it seems to be the approximate threshold for instability.  Even so, `MaxSteps -> 100000` is necessary to reach `l == 1`.  As noted by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in a comment, `NDSolve` immediately issues

```
NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable p. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>
```

and this is correct.  The system needs two boundary conditions at constant `p` but has none.  This may be the root of the problem.  (Without the need boundary conditions, `NDSolve` in effect makes some up.)  Later, `NDSolve` also issues the `NDSolve::eerr:` warning.  To see at least the symptoms of this problem, it is helpful to plot the solution.

```
Plot3D[U[l, p] /. s2, {l, 0, 1}, {p, -1.5, 4}, AxesLabel -> {l, p, U}]
```

[image]

which looks reasonable, apart from a few blemishes.  However, the denominator `(1 + D[U[l, p], p] + 2 p D[U[l, p], {p, 2}])` is worrisome, so it too is plotted.

```
Plot3D[(1 + D[U[l, p] /. s2, p] + 2 p D[U[l, p] /. s2, {p, 2}]) /. 
    p -> q, {l, 0, 1}, {q, -1.5, 4}, AxesLabel -> {l, p, U}, PlotRange -> {-.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

and it shows a developing instability.  Moreover, the quantity goes through zero, first at about `{0.62, -1.5}`.  Thereafter, the solution is meaningless.  So, it is essential to provide boundary conditions, with at least one of them at the minimum value of `p`.  I tried the obvious,

```
(D[U[l, p], p] /. p -> -1.5) == 0, (D[U[l, p], p] /. p -> 4)==0
```

but it only increased the instability.

Incidentally, replacing `u0v = .01` by `u0v = 1/100` also increased the instability.  Bizarre!