# Boundary conditions are not satisfied with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to study the time evolution of a small perturbation around the static solution of the following Wave Equation

$$
-\partial_t^2 v(t,r) + \partial_r^2v(t,r) + \frac{2}{r}\partial_r v(t,r) = \frac{\partial V(v)}{\partial v}(t,r)
$$

for some expression of the potential $V(v)$ that is written in the code below. The coordinates $t,r$ run over $[0,+\infty]$.

By definition, the static solution $\hat{v}(r)$ is time-independent and I require the following initial/boundary conditions

$$
\partial_r \hat{v}(r)|_{r=0} =0\,,\qquad \hat{v}(r \rightarrow +\infty) = 0.
$$

Obviously, to perform numerical computations the limit $r\rightarrow+\infty$ is replaced by $r=M$ where $M\gg \ell$ where $\ell$ is the characteristic length of the problem; it turns out to be $\ell \sim 2$ for the static solution.

I want to perturb this solution at $t=0$ and see how it evolves with time. So, now I am interested in the time-dependent solution which satisfies

$$
v(t=0,r) = \hat{v}(r)\,\qquad \partial_t v(r,t)|_{t=0}=\delta \cdot 10^{-2}\,,\\
\partial_r v(t,r)|_{r=0}=0\,, \qquad v(r=M) = 0.
$$

where $\delta\ll 1$.

- While the numerical static solution satisfies $\hat{v}'(r=0)=0$, the time-dependent solution I got does not. I don't understand why. For a specific example with $\delta = 0.001$, I get $\partial_r v(t,r) \sim -0.000701892$ irrespectively of the value of the time variable `t`. In particular, it looks the initial condition $v(t=0,r) = \hat{v}(r)$ is not satisfied. Is this normal?
- Moreover, I get the error [image], why? Are my boundary conditions really inconsistent?

This is my code.

```
V[v_] = (-1 + (1/8 (-9 + Sqrt[145]) - v)^2)^2 + 3 (1/8 (-9 + Sqrt[145]) - v)^3;

sol[rmax_, \[Delta]_] := Last@Last@ Last@NDSolve[{+D[v[r], {r, 2}] + 2/r D[v[r], {r, 1}] - (D[V[v], v] /. v -> v[r]) == 0, (D[v[r], r] /. r -> SetPrecision[10^-10, 100]) == 0, v[SetPrecision[10^-10, 100]] == SetPrecision[\[Delta], 100]}, v, {r, 10^-10, rmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> "Extrapolation"]

iTf = sol[30, 1.506400187591933106770472351];
Plot[{iTf[r]}, {r, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]

iTfTime = v /. ParametricNDSolve[{-D[v[t, r], {t, 2}] + D[v[t, r], {r, 2}] + 2/r D[v[t, r], {r, 1}] - (D[V[v], v] /. v -> v[t, r]) == 0, v[0, r] == iTf[r], ((D[v[t, r], t]) /. t -> 0) == +\[Delta] 10^-2, (D[v[t, r], r] /. r -> 10^-10) == 0,v[t,30]==0}, v, {t, 0, 40}, {r, 10^-10, 30}, {\[Delta]}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 200}}, PrecisionGoal -> 15]

iTfTimeToPlot0 = iTfTime[0.001];

(*Checking boundary conditions in generic points*)
((D[iTfTimeToPlot0[t, r], t] /. t -> 0) /. r -> RandomReal[]) == +0.001 10^-2
(*Output: True*)

((D[iTfTimeToPlot0[t, r], r] /. r -> 10^-10) /. t -> RandomReal[]) == 0
(*Output: False*)
```

**Update**

I have tried adding the following method

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}
```

but still the two solutions ($v(t=0,r)$ and $\hat{v}(r)$ differs for small values of $r$, instead they should coincide given the boundary condition)

```
iTfTime = v /. ParametricNDSolve[{-D[v[t, r], {t, 2}] + D[v[t, r], {r, 2}] + 2/r D[v[t, r], {r, 1}] - (D[V[v], v] /. v -> v[t, r]) == 0, v[0, r] == iTf[r], ((D[v[t, r], t]) /. t -> 0) == +\[Delta] 10^-2, (D[v[t, r], r] /. r -> 10^-10) == 0, v[t, 30] == 0}, v, {t, 0, 40}, {r, 10^-10, 30}, {\[Delta]},  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]

iTfTimeToPlot = iTfTime[0.001]
Plot[{iTfTimeToPlot[0, r], iTf[r]}, {r, 10^-10, 0.003}, PlotRange -> All]
```

(*Output: [image] *)

Comment: 1. The b.c. at $r=M$ isn't included in the code. Though `NDSolve` doesn't spit out `bcart`, please notice this will still cause severe problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141364/pde-with-ndsolve-gives-solution-despite-not-enough-boundary-conditions#comment382152_141364 2. Have you read this post?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871

Comment: Isn't included because I think it is redundant given the dynamics of the equation. The static solution already satisfies it and I expect this to hold. However, I have tried adding this boundary condition and nothing changes.

Comment: @xzczd I have seen the problem is solved by adding `AccuracyGoal -> 6` when solving the time-dependent solution. Now, it gives me the solution but it returns the message `Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate` is too large. However, the solution looks nice, but its merely an accident

Comment: @xzczd How could I have understood the value of `AccuracyGoal` in order to catch the solution?? This is a mystery.....

Comment: 1. The missing of b.c. at $r=M$ doesn't seem to cause problem in this case, but it's no more than an accident, please add all the necessary b.c. to the code. 2. Please read the post linked above about `ibcinc` warning. 3. AFAIK, struggling with `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` is almost always the wrong way to go when dealing with PDE, for more info please read this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the boundary condition at $r=M$. I have also read the links, I am going to try to solve the issue.

Comment: @xzczd I had a look to the links, however I didn't find any useful informations to understand why NDSolve does not give a solution that satisfies the b.c. at r=0. Do you have more hints?

Comment: …Have you tried adding the option mentioned there and recheck?

Comment: @xzczd Sure. I have tried adding `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}` but still the spatial initial condition (that is the derivative wrt `r` evaluated at `r=10^-10`) is not satisfied.

Comment: But they're much closer. Well, it's midnight here, if you still have difficulty in understanding, I can try finding some time to elaborate with an answer tomorrow, perhaps.

Comment: @xzczd Sure, don't worry. I have edited the question with the updates. My actual problem is much more difficult, this is just a toy model which I should be able to solve.

Comment: ……Why is there a `v[t,rmax]==0}` in definition of `sol`?

Comment: @xzczd ops... It's just a typo in the code here in SE. I have added this condition on my code after your comment, but then I didn't copy all the code here. Just modified it in the wrong place. I edit the question.

Comment: @xzczd Now, it is `v[t,30]==0` in the definition of `iTfTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been hesitant about whether I should mark this question as duplicate or not for quite a while, but finally decide to post an answer to elaborate because the relationship between OP's question and

[2D Heat equation: inconsistent boundary and initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20729/1871)

may be not immediately clear.

In short, it's all because the spatial grid is not dense enough, so the **interpolation error** shows up, even if you've added `"MinPoints" -> 200`, given the requirement for precision is so demanding. Adding `"ScaleFactor" -> 1` (as discussed in detail in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871)) is a relatively cheap way to relief this.

Let's increase the spatial grid points to `1500` and recheck:

```
mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

r0 = 10^-10; rmax = 30; tmax = 40;

iTfTime = v /. 
   ParametricNDSolve[{-D[v[t, r], {t, 2}] + D[v[t, r], {r, 2}] + 
       2/r D[v[t, r], {r, 1}] - (D[V[v], v] /. v -> v[t, r]) == 0,

     v[0, r] == iTf[r],
     ((D[v[t, r], t]) /. t -> 0) == +δ 10^-2,
     (D[v[t, r], r] /. r -> r0) == 0,
     v[t, rmax] == 0}, v, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, r0, rmax}, {δ}, 
    Method -> Union[mol[1500, 2], mol[True, 1]]];

iTfTimeToPlot = iTfTime[0.001];
Plot[{iTfTimeToPlot[0, r], iTf[r]}, {r, r0, 0.003}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

```
D[iTfTimeToPlot[0, r], r] /. r -> r0
(* 0.0000370957 *)

D[iTfTimeToPlot[20, r], r] /. r -> r0
(* 7.07301*10^-11 *)

Plot[D[iTfTimeToPlot[t, r], r] /. r -> r0 // Evaluate, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[iTfTimeToPlot[t, r], {r, r0, rmax/4}, PlotRange -> {-1/2, 3/2}], {t, 0, 
  tmax/4}]
```

*GIF made with 9.0.1 because 11.3 isn't at hand, but the result just looks the same.*

[image]

The `0.0000370957` at $t=0$ is, as already mentioned, interpolation error:

```
iTfinter = Interpolation@Array[{#, iTf@#} &, 1500, {r0, rmax}];
iTfinter'[r0]
(* 0.0000370957281084964292812983780513760449138607 *)
```

BTW here's another post about interpolation error:

[How to avoid this kind of numerical error caused by extreme parameters when using NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10055/1871)

Comment: Thank you. However, the solution behaves correctly at values $r> 1$, while for small values $r \sim 0$ but still $r>10^{-10}$ the solution oscillates, look at the red square here https://ibb.co/M1FDNdj. This is not good.... this problem is related to the interpolation error, right? I am going to read the link you referred to.

Comment: @apt45 Can't reproduce in _v11.3_, which version are you in? What code did you use to generate the plot?

Comment: I also use v11.3. Here you can download the notebook https://www.dropbox.com/s/gal9yav4caw06ec/example.nb?dl=0

Comment: Try this `Plot[iTfTimeToPlot[3.6, r], {r, 10^-10, 1}, PlotRange -> All]` I get this plot https://ibb.co/DzQBYY1

Comment: @apt45 1. Please avoid sharing code with external download links. 2. Can't reproduce the result at `t==3.6`, either. 3. Are you facing the problem mentioned here?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191358/solving-system-of-differential-equations-in-loop-with-recursive-variable/1194930#comment507444_194930

Comment: How your solution looks like in $r \in [10^{-10},1]$ for `t==3.6`? We have the same version of Mathematica, running the same code and we get different results. I have tried to quit the kernel, restart mathematica and nothing changed.

Comment: @apt45 Check my update.

Comment: Do you get that NDSolve fails to integrate at around `t==19`?? I get `ParametricNDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 19.433431183124842`.` and the solution starts to be crazy

Comment: @apt45 No, `ibcinc` is the only warning I obtain. I only plotted up to `tmax/4` because the solution later isn't that interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92860/discussion-between-apt45-and-xzczd).