# Solving systems of partial differential equations with functions of different number of variables

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of two partial differential equations

$\partial_t G(x,y,t) + \partial_x G(x,y,t)+\partial_y G(x,y,t) = -i\left[f(x,t) + f(y,t)\right] $

$\partial_t f(x,t) + \partial_x f(x,t) = f(x,t) - iG(x,0,t)$

with initial conditions $f(x,0)=0$ and $G(x,y,0) = G_0(x,y)$ where $G_0$ is a given function (e.g., a double Gaussian packet in the x-y plane)

I tried the following code:

```
L = 1; T = 1; x0 = -L/4; sigma = L/30; 
sol = NDSolve[{
   D[G[x, y, t], t] == -(D[G[x, y, t], x] + D[G[x, y, t], y]) - I*(f[x, t] + f[y, t]),
    D[f[x, t], t] == -D[f[x, t], x] + f[x, t] - I*(G[x, 0, t]),
    G[x, y, 0] == Exp[-((x - x0)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma))^2 - ((y - x0)/(Sqrt[2]*sigma))^2],
    f[x, 0] == 0
   },
  {G, f}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T},
  MaxSteps -> 500]`
```

But I get the errors:

```
Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {x,y,t} to be filled from Function[{x,y,t},0][x,t].

Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {x,y,t} to be filled from Function[{x,y,t},0][-0.5,0.].

Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {x,y,t} to be filled from Function[{x,y,t},0][-0.5,0.].

General::stop: Further output of Function::fpct will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at y == 0.`.

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at y == 0.`.
```

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: The warning is probably because you forgot to `Clear[f]` first. Then you need to add proper artificial b.c. for your problem because otherwise we won't know what b.c. is added to `NDSolve`. (See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871) for more information. ) The most troublesome part `f[x, t] + f[y, t]` still remains though, but I think it's not too hard to overcome. If you supplement proper b.c., I can have a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Using Clear[f] before the code did not remove the warning.
Regarding the boundary conditions: I expect the initial "pulse" (in the xy plane) never to approach the boundaries, so probably the exact boundary conditions are not important. I think periodic boundary conditions should work, or whatever else you think it may be easy to implement.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I'd like to point out the warning `Function::fpct` is probably because you've executed `f = Function[{x, y, t}, 0];` and forgotten to `Clear[f]` then. This isn't the main issue, of course.

The main issue is, currently `NDSolve` can't handle equation system whose unknown functions are defined on different domains. (In your case, $G\in [-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}]\times[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}]\times[0,T]$ and $f\in [-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}]\times[0,T]$. ) So let's discretize the system to an ODE system ourselves.

I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of ODEs.

First, supplement b.c. to the system. Since you've mentioned b.c. isn't important here, I simply use zero Dirichlet b.c.:

```
L = 1; T = 1; x0 = -L/4; sigma = L/30;
domain = {-L/2, L/2};
{eq1, eq2} = {D[G[x, y, t], t] == -(D[G[x, y, t], x] + D[G[x, y, t], y]) - 
     I (f[x, y, t] + f2[x, y, t]), 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -D[f[x, t], x] + f[x, t] - I (G2[x, t])};

{ic1, ic2} = {G[x, y, 0] == 
    Exp[-((x - x0)/(Sqrt[2] sigma))^2 - ((y - x0)/(Sqrt[2] sigma))^2], f[x, 0] == 0};

{bc1, bc2} = {G[x, y, t] == 0 /. Outer[{# -> #2} &, {x, y}, domain],
   f[x, t] == 0 /. List /@ Thread[x -> domain]};
```

Notice I've modified the form of PDE system a bit (`f[x, t] -> f[x, y, t]`, `f[y, t] -> f2[x, y, t]`, `G[x, 0, t] -> G2[x, t]` ) because `pdetoode` can't handle functions defined in different domains all in once, either.

Next step is discretization. I've defined 2 functions `ptoofunc1` and `ptoofunc2` for the discretization of 2 domains.

```
points = 71; 
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)

ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[{G, f, f2}[x, y, t], t, {grid, grid}, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[{G2, f}[x, t], t, grid, difforder];

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
rule1 = {f[x_, y_][t_] :> f[x][t], f2[x_, y_][t_] :> f[y][t]};
rule2 = G2[x_][t_] :> G[x, 0][t];
ode1 = del /@ del@ptoofunc1@eq1 /. rule1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2 /. rule2;
odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
```

Notice `points` should be an odd number, or `G[x, 0, t]` won't be properly handled.

`del` is a function for deleting equations at boundary to "make room" for b.c.s because `ptoofunc1` and `ptoofunc2` generate equations for every grid points. `rule1` and `rule2` is for transforming `f2` and `G2` back to `f` and `g`.

```
diff = With[{sf = 1}, diffbc[t, sf]];
odebc1 = diff@MapAt[del /@ # &, ptoofunc1@bc1, {1}];
odebc2 = diff@ptoofunc2@bc2;
```

`diff` is for transforming the disretized b.c. to (almost) equivalent ODEs. Well I admit the code above is a bit advanced, to have a better understanding for the whole process you may want to read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

The last step is to solve the system and rebuild the solutions to 2 interpolating functions:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, odeic1, odeic2, odebc1, odebc2}, {Outer[G, grid, grid], 
    f /@ grid}, {t, 0, T}];

solG = rebuild[sol[[1]], {grid, grid}, 3];
solf = rebuild[sol[[2]], grid, 2];
```

Let's check the solution:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[solG[x, y, t] // Evaluate , {x, ##}, {y, ##}, 
        PlotRange -> {-0.1, 1}], {t, 0, T}] & @@ domain
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[solf[x, t] // Abs // Evaluate, {x, ##}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}], {t, 0, 
    T}] & @@ domain
```

[image]

If you prefer periodic b.c.:

```
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[{G, f, f2}[x, y, t], t, {grid, grid}, difforder, True];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[{G2, f}[x, t], t, grid, difforder, True];
    
ode1 = ptoofunc1@eq1 /. rule1;
ode2 = ptoofunc2@eq2 /. rule2;
odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;

sol = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, odeic1, odeic2}, {Outer[G, grid, grid], f /@ grid}, {t, 
    0, T}];

solG = rebuild[sol[[1]], {grid, grid}, 3];
solf = rebuild[sol[[2]], grid, 2];
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well from the link below DSolve , in this stage of development can only handle 2 independent variables. 
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroductionToPDEs.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if the same limit applies to NDSolve? I could not find anything in the the documentation.