# I understand mol but meet difficulty in understanding how `pdetoode` atumatically generate pde-to-ode-rules by using this strange pattern and rule?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, pattern-matching, rule

I often solve pdes for my research, and years ago I found `pdetoode` in this forum is very handy. Although it is a small piece of code, it solves several interesting and challenging pdes ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230429/nonlinear-dispersal-equation-modeling-insect-aggregation/230431#230431) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184281/why-does-ndsolve-fail-to-solve-the-pdes-and-spit-out-mconly-warning/184285#184285) for example) in this forum.

Thus, I decied to figure out its working principle, because I strongly believe that it is greatly benificial to both ode and Mathematica understandings.

I have been studying hard on the package `pdetoode` by xzczd for many times and many days each time I picks it up.

I still can't figure out the how the pde converted to odes.

In particularlly, the following command:

```
((u : func) | Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[
  x1 : pat, t_, x2___] :>
 (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2};
  fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> o, PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic])
```

I guess from the context that `pat` here means whatever repeats itself several times exactly. However, for code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160012/solving-systems-of-partial-differential-equations-with-functions-of-different-nu/160105#160105), after I print `dx1`, and `x1`. In some cases `dx1 = 0 1`, `x1=x y` , **this confues me a lot**.

I also attempt to use `Trace` on `pdetoode`, but its long long out confuses me more.

**How can this be? Maybe I misunderstand something here?
What does this piece of code try to do?**

I tried my best but I still fails to understand it.

Can anyone explain something on the above code or `pdetoode`? Thanks!

In order to  analyze how `pdetoode` works, below is the code that I used to `Print` some local variables. The confusing printed information mentioned above is shown in the following figure.

[image: Confusing Printed Information of pdetoode]

```
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;

Clear[fdd, pde2ode, tooderule, pdetoae, rebuild]

(*====== fdd =======*)

fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_, periodic_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;


(*====== pde2ode =======*)

pde2ode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  With[{s = Style[#, Purple, Bold] &}, 
   Print[s@"pde2ode-1 ********************************"];
   Print[s@"funcvalue = ", s@funcvalue]; Print[s@"rest = ", s@rest];
   pde2ode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], 
    rest]];

pde2ode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  With[{s = Style[#, Red, Bold] &}, 
   Print[s@"pde2ode-2 ********************************"];
   Print[s@"func = ", s@func]; Print[s@"var = ", s@var]; 
   Print[s@"rest = ", s@rest];
   pde2ode[Alternatives[func][var], rest]];

pde2ode[front__ (* front : u[x,t],t *), grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer, 
   periodic_ : False] := 
  With[{s = Style[#, Blue, Bold] &}, 
   Print[s@"pde2ode-3 ********************************"];
   Print[s@"front = ", s@front]; Print[s@"grid = ", s@grid];
   pde2ode[front, {grid}, o, periodic]];

pde2ode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer, 
   periodic : True | False | {(True | False) ..} : False] :=
  
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]},
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, 
     pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]},
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
        MapThread[
         Piecewise[{{1, PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[1]]]}, {-1, 
             PossibleZeroQ[# - #2[[-1]]]}}, All] &, {coord, 
          bound}]]},
     With[{s = Style[#, Darker[Green], Bold] &}, 
      Print[s@"pde2ode-core *****************************"];
      Print[s@"func = ", s@func]; Print[s@"time = ", s@time]; 
      Print[s@"grid = ", s@grid];
      Print[s@"pos = ", s@pos]; Print[s@"bound = ", s@bound]; 
      Print[s@"spacevar = ", s@spacevar]; 
      Print[s@"coordtoindex = ", s@coordtoindex]];
     tooderule@Flatten@{
        (*------- 
        rule_1 --------*)
        ((u : func) | 
            Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, 
          t_, 
          x2___] :>
         (With[{}, Print["-------------"]; 
           Print["u = ", u]; Print["dx1 = ", dx1]; 
           Print["pat = ", pat]; Print["dt = ", dt]; 
           Print["dx2 = ", dx2]; Print["x1 = ", x1]; 
           Print["x2 = ", x2]];
          Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2}; 
          With[{}, Print["coord = ", {x1, x2}]; 
           Print["coordtoindex[coord] = ", coordtoindex@{x1, x2}]];
          
          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, 
           Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o, PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic]),
        (*------- rule_2 --------*)
        
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, 
          Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]
        }]]];


(*====== tooderule =======*)

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. 
   eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]


(*====== pdetoae =======*)

pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Function[
     pde, #[
       pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
          Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> 
          u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[i__][t] :> u[i]] &@
   pde2ode[func[var, t], t, rest]]


(*====== rebuild =======*)

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_?VectorQ, timeposition_ : 1] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, {grid}, timeposition]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_?Negative] := 
 rebuild[funcarray, grid, Range[Length@grid + 1][[timeposition]]]

rebuild[funcarray_, grid_, timeposition_ : 1] /; 
  Dimensions@funcarray === Length /@ grid := 
 With[{depth = Length@grid}, 
  ListInterpolation[
     Transpose[
      Map[Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] &, #, {depth}], 
      Append[Delete[Range[depth + 1], timeposition], timeposition]], 
     Insert[grid, Flatten[#][[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], 
      timeposition]] &@funcarray]
(*=================== example of pdetoode ================*)

L = 1; T = 1; x0 = -L/4; sigma = L/30;
domain = {-L/2, L/2};
{eq1, eq2} = {D[G[x, y, t], t] == -(D[G[x, y, t], x] + D[G[x, y, t], y]) - 
     I (f[x, y, t] + f2[x, y, t]), 
   D[f[x, t], t] == -D[f[x, t], x] + f[x, t] - I (G2[x, t])};

{ic1, ic2} = {G[x, y, 0] == 
    Exp[-((x - x0)/(Sqrt[2] sigma))^2 - ((y - x0)/(Sqrt[2] sigma))^2], 
   f[x, 0] == 0};

{bc1, bc2} = {G[x, y, t] == 0 /. Outer[{# -> #2} &, {x, y}, domain], 
   f[x, t] == 0 /. List /@ Thread[x -> domain]};

points = 5;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

difforder = 2;

ptoofunc1 = 
 pde2ode[{G[x, y, t], f[x, y, t], f2[x, y, t]}, t, {grid, grid}, difforder]

grid
ptoofunc2 = pde2ode[{G2[x, t], f[x, t]}, t, grid, difforder];

ptoofunc1 = 
 pde2ode[{G, f, f2}[x, y, t], t, {grid, grid}, difforder]

ptoofunc2 = pde2ode[{G2, f}[x, t], t, grid, difforder];


del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
rule1 = {f[x_, y_][t_] :> f[x][t], f2[x_, y_][t_] :> f[y][t]};
ode1 = del /@ del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode1 = del /@ del@ptoofunc1@eq1 /. rule1;

rule2 = G2[x_][t_] :> G[x, 0][t];
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2 /. rule2;

odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;

odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;


diff = With[{sf = 1}, D[#, t] + #] &;
odebc1 = Map[diff, MapAt[del /@ # &, ptoofunc1@bc1, {1}], {-2}];

odebc2 = Map[diff, ptoofunc2@bc2, {-2}];

sol = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, odeic1, odeic2, odebc1, 
    odebc2}, {Outer[G, grid, grid], f /@ grid}, {t, 0, T}];

solG = rebuild[sol[[1]], {grid, grid}, 3];
solf = rebuild[sol[[2]], grid, 2];

(*Manipulate[Plot3D[solG[x,y,t]//Evaluate,{x,##},{y,##},PlotRange->{-0.1,1}],{\
t,0,T}]&@@domain*)

Manipulate[
   Plot[solf[x, t] // Abs // Evaluate, {x, ##}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}], {t, 0,
     T}] & @@ domain
```

Comment: Is `pdetoode` definition in general clear for you?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Thanks for your attention. I think I have a clear understanding until the `coordtoindex` and the above delayed rule, and can't go further. Actually I tried to understand `pdetoode` by it application to this 3D time dependent pde here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160012/solving-systems-of-partial-differential-equations-with-functions-of-different-nu/160105#160105

Comment: Do you understand that `pdetoode` is just  implementation the method of lines  with using  NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, I think I understand `mol` and I have carefully read through the "AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica.pdf" several times. I can solve some pdes with Mathematica using 'mol'. But the code is ugly, not as general as `pdetoode`, and this is another movtivation that I started to try to understand 'pdetoode'

Comment: Ok! Then the author of `pdetoode` has a good answer for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand the source code, let's first re-visit the syntax of `pdetoode`.

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
pdetoode[u[variables], t, grid, differenceorder, periodic]
pdetoode[{u, v, …}[variables], t, {grid1, grid2, …}, differenceorder, periodic]
pdetoode[{u[variables], v[variables],…},t, {grid1, grid2, …}, differenceorder, periodic]
```

As mentioned [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871):

> The syntax of `pdetoode` is as follows: 1st argument is the function
> to be discretized (which can be a list i.e. `pdetoode` can handle PDE system), 2nd argument is the independent variable in the
> resulting ODE system (usually it's the variable playing the role of
> "time" in the underlying model), 3rd argument is the list of
> spatial grid, 4th argument is difference order, 5th argument is to determine whether periodic b.c. should be set or not. (5th argument is optional, the default setting is `False`. )

<strike>Well, sometimes I feel that this syntax is a design miss, perhaps I should have made the syntax more simlar with `NDSolve`.</strike>  We know, method of lines is a method that discretizes PDE(s) to a system of ODEs i.e. we need to discretize all the independent variables except for `t` (to be preciser, the independent variable of the resulting ODEs). For example, if the original dependent variable is `u[x, t, y]`, it'll eventually be transformed to something equivalent to

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
Outer[{x, y}|->u[x, y][t], gridx, gridy]
```

If it's `Derivative[1, 1, 1][u][x, t, y]`, it's transformed to something equivalent to

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[{1, 1}, {gridx, gridy}, 
                                   Outer[{x, y}|->u[x, y]'[t], gridx, gridy], …]
```

Notice this is done with a single `fdd` in the source code.

To automate the process, it's clear we need to know the **pos**ition of `t`. This is programmatically detected by

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]
```

We also need to extract `x`, `y`, etc., because we need to determine whether we are discretizing b.c. or not (`pdetoode` can directly handle b.c. by design! ), and this is done by

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
…
pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}]
…
… [x1 : pat, t_, x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2}; …
```

Notice here the pattern inside `Repeated` is an unnamed pattern `_`, so it's just for restricting the length of the sequence, the elements of the sequence don't need to be exactly the same. If you still feel confused, try the following and think about why it *works*:

```
{a, b, c} /. {Repeated[_, {2}], c} :> "This matches of course"
(* "This matches of course" *)
```

The function `coordtoindex` detects whether the discretized equation is a b.c. or not. If it's left boundary, it outputs `-1`; right boundary, `1`; not a boundary, `All`. These are all indexes for `Part` (`[[]]`). The output is throwed out by `Sow` and catched by `Reap` in the function

```
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]
```

For example, if we're discretizing `u[x, t, y]` in the domain $[1,4]\times[2,3]$, then `u[1, t, y]` will finally evaluate to something equivalent to

```
(* The following isn't a working sample,
   it's just for illustration. *)
Outer[{x, y}|->u[x, y][t], gridx, gridy][[-1, All]]
```

Hope now it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In your response, I think I am clear before the last line "We also need to extract x, y, etc.". It is the `pat` that I am so confused. I thought `dx1, dx2` are spatial derivative orders right? For example in `Derivative[1,2,3,1][u][x,y,z,t]`, then`pat = Repeated[_, {3}]`,  so `dx1 = 1,2,3` should not mathch the `pat`. Thus, how can the spatial derivative orders be extracted by this rule? Could you please explain in more detail about this pattern?

Comment: @xinxin No, it matches. Notice it's an unnamed pattern `_`.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Finally! Your explanation is crystal clear! I mixed up `Repeated[x_,{3}]` and `x: Reapeated[_,{3}]` and the word `Repeat` in this command gives me a strong impression that something is repeated it self. 

Also, could please explain a little about `coordtoindex` function. It seems maps min and max coordinates to 1 and -1 and this makes sense to me. But, if I understand coorectly,why the other part that `coordtoinex` maps `All` to `All`? How the two `All`s works in this function?

Comment: @xinxin `x: Repeated[_, {3}]` still matches, but if it's `Repeated[x_, {3}]`, then it won't match. As to `coordtoindex`, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. The picture of `pdetoode` is becoming more and more clear for me with your explains. It would be take much longer for me to figure out "The function coordtoindex detects whether the discretized equation is a b.c. or not.". Actually, I and my classmates majored in civil engineering all learned so much from you in baidu tieba (we believe xzcyr is xzczd), mmaqa and here. We are not in famous 985 or 211 colleges, but we are so lucky to have guys like you in China, you makes us see deeply the power and beautify of Mathematica. Respect!