# Automatic boundary conditions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to know what kind of boundary conditions *Mathematica* implements in `NDSolve` when not specifying any boundary conditions by hand. So for example solving the transport equation:

```
eq = With[{l= 2.}, D[u[t, x], t] + l D[u[t, x], x] == 0];
mol[n_Integer, o_Integer] := {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> o, "Coordinates" -> N[-1 + 2/n*Range[0, n]]}}
solv = NDSolve[{eq, u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2/.1]}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, Method -> mol[51, 4]]
Animate[Plot[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. solv], {x, -1, 1}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

This gives me a warning:

> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.

but the equation is still solved. The boundary conditions at $+1$ look like absorbing or periodic boundary conditions but at $-1$ there is something different going on.

- How does *Mathematica* treat problems when no boundary condition is given in `NDSolve`?
- How can I implement in this case absorbing boundary conditions within `NDSolve`?

Edit: I was asked to edit the question to make it 'unique': Firstly my question refers *only* to the above stated (first order) transport equation, secondly my question also asks for implementing absorbing boundary condition which is kind of done automatically by mathematica at $+1$, thirdly I am not applying any boundary conditions *at all* which is different to [the question mentioned in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/what-boundary-is-added-when-boundary-condition-is-not-sufficient) and the mentioned question does not explain what `NDSolve` is doing at the edges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What boundary is added when boundary condition is not sufficient?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/what-boundary-is-added-when-boundary-condition-is-not-sufficient)

Comment: OK, I retracted my close vote because the "implementing absorbing boundary condition" part isn't included in the question above, but, "the mentioned question does not explain what `NDSolve` is doing at the edges." this is explained in the last link in that question, please read it carefully.

Comment: Could you point out where exactly this is explained? Do you mean: "So, perhaps we'll have to admit the solution is really meaningless in the end"?
I want to know how `NDSolve` is constructing the derivative at the outermost points. Is it using a forward difference scheme on the rhs and a backward scheme on the lhs? Or adding discretization points to the edges and applying some values to them? I cant see this being answered clearly in the link.

Comment: It's **one-sided formula** that's used at edges. You can search these words in that page and read the relevant part.

Comment: I've posted a related question [in scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28744/5331) and started a bounty for it but haven't got a satisfied answer so far…

Comment: This is just only seemingly a none oscillatory differential equation. Interpret this as a iterative Fourier transformation. This is collecting from the error terms more and more higher order harmonics of the solution superposed on the solution. Mathematica can deal this behaviour with several methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this method inside NDSolve

```
solv = NDSolve[{eq, u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2/.1]},u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
"SpatialDiscretization" ->       {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" ->{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.03}}}]
```

the warning gives some other useful information.

```
(* NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. *)
```

In case of insufficient boundary conditions, I think  NDSolve uses "Neumann boundary value"

Comment: (-1) I'm sorry, but this is irrelevant to OP's question. The boundary treatment is very different when `"FiniteElement"` is chosen for `"SpatialDiscretization"`. Just compare your result to OP's and you'll see the difference. For more information, check the links I gave in the comment above.

Comment: I don't think so. Just look in the help documentation `NeumannValue` .

Comment: `"FiniteElement"` together with `NeumannValue` etc. is added after _v10_, while OP's problem has existed long before that.

Comment: The question has been posed in  Jan 2018! I don't know which MMA version   is involved. But please be aware, that I tried to give a helpful *relevant* answer. Your hastly judgement appears to be dispensable.

Comment: I mean, the problem that `bcart` warning points to has existed long before _v10_ and is not relevant to `"FiniteElement"`. (Notice OP has manually chosen `"TensorProductGrid"` method, and even if he doesn't manually choose this, it's the default method in this case. ) Once again, please check the links I gave in the comment above and you'll see some detailed discussion.