# Inconsistent of initial and boundary condition in 1D PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I am now dealing with the 1D PDE with periodic boundary condition given by the following:

$$
\partial_{t}u(t,x) = \partial_{x}u(t,x). \quad \text{with}\quad u(0,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-\pi/4)^2/2}\quad u(t,-\pi)=u(t,\pi)
$$

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, \[Theta]]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Theta]\)]\(u[t, \[Theta]]\)\) == 
 0, u[0, \[Theta]] == Exp[-(\[Theta] - \[Pi]/4)^2], 
u[t, -\[Pi]] == u[t, \[Pi]]}, 
u, {t, 0, 0.1, 20}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
   "MinPoints" -> 200}}, PrecisionGoal -> 1];

plots = Table[Plot[ufun[t, \[Theta]], {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]},PlotRange -> {0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"], {t, 0, 
20, .1}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

Although there is no error, the solution is not expected.

[image]

I have tried the solution here [2D Heat equation: inconsistent boundary and initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/2d-heat-equation-inconsistent-boundary-and-initial-conditions?rq=1).

```
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
           "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 20}}
```

It seems doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: How about using `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid",  "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 200}`?  That fixed it for me.  Also, is `PrecisionGoal -> 1` necessary?

Comment: @ChrisK It works! But I still didn't get it how does the these mesh affect the stability and why mathematica does not do these automatically?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but when I run your code it gives a warning `Using maximum number of grid points 10000`.  Such a fine mesh size may mean that time steps need to be quite small to satisfy the [Courant condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy_condition).  I suppose numerically solving PDEs is a hard problem for Mathematica to make the right decisions on, so sometimes the user has to make the appropriate choice of numerical parameters.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I am wondering if there is a way to adaptively adjust the mesh to save memory and time (in 2D problem).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that.  You might open another question on it if the 2D problem actually turns out to be problematic.

Comment: The time step of PDE solver is adaptive, but the spatial step is not (at least now). You can refer to `tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines` for more information

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! Btw, I am wondering if the unbounded transport equation can be solved by NDSolve perfectly or not? Do you think specifying a periodic boundary condition at some far away point like x=100 & -100 can mimic an unbounded problem?

Comment: To solve unbounded problem numerically, as you've noticed, artificial b.c. is often needed, but I never found material about artificial b.c. for transport equation. ([This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163793/1871) is a related post, don't miss the links there. ) The reason might be that, the analytic solution for transport equation is known and very simple. So I think it's better to solve transport equation analytically.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, you are right. Dsolve always treats this problem well. However, when I run into 2D problem ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180104/unstable-solution-of-2d1-time-pde-with-periodic-boundary-condition)), it seems to be inevitable to deal with this problem numerically like convection-dominated problem.

Comment: @ChrisK Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, without setting `"MaxPoints"`, `NDSolve` uses 10000 grid points, which makes it hard to solve, maybe due to the [Courant condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition).  Adding `"MaxPoints"->200` fixes it.  I also removed `PrecisionGoal->1` and changed the `t` range specification in `NDSolve`.

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{
  D[u[t, θ] , t] + D[u[t, θ], θ] == 0, 
  u[0, θ] == Exp[-(θ - π/4)^2], 
  u[t, -π] == u[t, π]}, 
  u, {t, 0, 20}, {θ, -π, π}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 200}}];
Plot[ufun[20, θ], {θ, -π, π}, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]