# Unstable solution of 2D+1 time PDE with periodic boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

Now I am trying to solve the following 2D+1 type of PDE:

$\partial_t u(t,x,y)=-y\partial_{x}u+\partial_{y}\left[a y+b sin(x)u+c\partial_{y}u\right]$

with $u(0,x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-((x-\pi/4)^2+y^2)/2}$

and periodic boundary condition:

$u(t,-\pi,y)=u(t,\pi,y)$

In $y$-direction, it is unbounded.

Here is the code:

```
a = 1;
T = 1;
ωcb = -50;
ωct = 50;
ωb = -5;
ωt = 5;
A = 10;
γ = 0.1;
kT = 0.1;
ufun = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, θ, ω], t] == -D[ω u[t, θ, ω], θ] - 
       D[-A Sin[θ] u[t, θ, ω] - γ kT D[u[t, θ, ω], ω], ω] + 0.1 D[ω u[t, θ, ω], ω], 
    u[0, θ, ω] == 
     1/(2 a π)
       E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - (ω)^2/(2 a^2)),
    u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], 
    u[t, θ, ωcb] == u[t, θ, ωct]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 
    T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωcb, ωct},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 1000}}];
plots = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[
     ufun[t, θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"], {t, 0, T, .1}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

The solution is a mess. I believe there are some problem on mesh?

[image]

Also there are some message

> NDSolveValue::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 1000 allowed
>   by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable
>   $\theta$.
>
> NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are
>   inconsistent.
>
> NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of
>   62.663959713694915`at t = 1.` in the direction of independent variable θ is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid
>   spacing with 1001 points may be too large to achieve the desired
>   accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid
>   spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method
>   options.

But when I try

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
           "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 10000}}
```

It cannot manage to finish the program. What's going on ? Thanks for any suggestion!

Reference:
[image]

Comment: Is this equation taken from literature or derived by yourself? Can you add some background information?

Comment: Yes, I derive it by myself. It's the Klein-Kramers equation or 2D Fokker-Planck equation in rotational coordinate with sinusoidal potential.

Comment: The initial data is not symmetric, so the periodic boundary conditions for the variable θ are inconsistent with the initial data.

Comment: We must pay attention to the code or the equations that are declared by the author? The equations in the code and in the beginning of the topic do not coincide.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I guess OP's equation in the code is a variant of the one in the reference. (He mentioned that "I derive it by myself" in his first comment. ) Of course this is something that OP should clarify.

Comment: @AlexTrounev as  xzczd said. These two equation on indeed in a same form.

Comment: And what equation do you propose to solve? I see at the beginning of the topic one equation, in the code - second, and the third in the end. In the formulation of the problem, the initial data are symmetric, while in the codes it is not symmetric. Why?

Comment: The exact equation is shown in code. For the initial condition, sorry about that... it is a typo. The initial condition in equation should be asymmetric in the code also.

Comment: Since you've mentioned $u$ is probability density in your [subsequent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180142/1871), are you sure the i.c. is `E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - ω^2/(2 a^2))/(2 a π)` rather than `E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - ω^2/(2 a^2))/(2 a^2 π)`? (Notice the difference in denominator. ) I find the original i.c. suspicious because `Integrate[E^(-((\[Theta] - \[Pi]/
            4)^2/(2 a^2)) - \[Omega]^2/(2 a^2))/(2 a \[Pi]), {\[Theta], -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {\[Omega], -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0]` outputs `a`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Since I set a=1, I didn't realize the problem here. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the [magic of `"Pseudospectral"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9291/1871):

```
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

With[{u = u[t, θ, ω]}, 
  eq = D[u, t] == -D[ω u, θ] - D[-A Sin[θ] u, ω] - γ kT D[u, ω] + 1/10 D[ω u, ω];

  ic = u == E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - ω^2/(2 a^2))/(2 a π) /. t -> 0];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], u[t, θ, ωcb] == u[t, θ, ωct]}, 
    u, {t, 0, T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωcb, ωct}, 
    Method -> mol[81]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {24.137131, Null} *)

plots = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[ufun[t, θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, 
     PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    BoxRatios -> {Pi, ωb, 1}], {t, 0, T, .04}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

[image]

---

## Update: A faster approach

Your equation turns out to be another example where the somewhat strange difference strategy discussed [in this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129183/1871) causes trouble, so the problem can be solved With the `fix` function in that post:

```
(* The fix function isn't included in this post, 
   please find it in the link above. *)
ufun = fix[T, 4]@
    NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], 
      u[t, θ, ωcb] == u[t, θ, ωct]}, 
     u, {t, 0, T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωcb, ωct}, 
     Method -> mol[81]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {13.415239, Null} *)
```

The resulting animation is similar so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: The method is good, but the problem is not correct, so we have a message on the output `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`

Comment: @Alex `ibcinc` warning pops up because the i.c. isn't periodic technically, but it's close to constant near $\theta=\pm \pi$ i.e. approximately periodic, so the warning isn't a big deal, I think. One can eliminate the warning by e.g. modifying i.c. to `With[{u = u[t, θ, ω]}, 
 ic = u == Piecewise[{{E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - ω^2/(2 a^2))/(
       2 a π), Abs@θ < 0.9 Pi}}] /. t -> 0]`, and the solution won't change much. Of course when the b.c. involves derivative, `ibcinc` often means fatal error, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871) for more information.

Comment: Note that the equations in the code and in the beginning of the topic do not coincide.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. Indeed, they looks different but essentially the same.

Comment: Could someone explain what's going on? I am confused with the method. What's the problem with my original code? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Any way to accelerate the computational time? like applying FEM or so.

Comment: If I change your code by setting T=10, then it becomes very difficult to solve. Is there any potential issue on time step?

Comment: @BobLin The problem of your original code is, the default method for spatial discretization doesn't work well for your equation. It's a rule of thumb that, `"Pseudospectral"` method may work well on PDE related to quantum mechanics and fluid dynamics, so I give it a try, and it works. `"Pseudospectral"` method is time and memory consuming compared to the default method, if `81` makes the code too slow, you may try a coarser grid e.g. `mol[35]` and see if the solution is accurate enough for you.

Comment: What's the meaning of the function mol and argument? Btw, do you think the Dirichlet boundary condition (specify by hand) in y-direction is necessary? In my original code, I set a periodic bc for y to mimic the situation without boundary.

Comment: @bob As to FEM, I don't think it'll help in this case, because you're solving the PDE in a simple domain and the coefficient is continuous, so there won't be a big difference between using `FiniteElement` method and `"{"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I see. Since the region is rectangle, there is no benefit from FEM.

Comment: @bob The `mol` function is a function I placed in my `SystemOpen@"init.m"`, because the options therein are frequently adjusted. `Method -> mol[35]` is amount to `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 35, "MinPoints" -> 35, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}`, check the document of `Pattern` and `Optional` for more information. As to the b.c. in y direction, I don't think it's _necessary_ to use Dirichlet b.c. for approximation of b.c. at infinity. You can try it out to see if it approximates the unbounded domain better, of course.

Comment: Just change a parameter a from 1 to 0.1. The solution still becomes unstable, do I have to refine the mesh?

Comment: @bob It's a possible choice, but I think it's better to make the domain smaller. Try `Table[a = 1/mid; 
 Plot3D[E^(-((θ - π/4)^2/(2 a^2)) - ω^2/(2 a^2))/(
  2 a π), {ω, -3, 3}, {θ, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All], {mid, 1, 5}]` and you'll know what I mean.

Comment: I know what you mean but the problem is time-dependent, unfortunately. Therefore, the peak is moving around. It's inevitable to specify such a large region, or?

Comment: @bob Oh… then the only choice is using a denser grid, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

I took the equations and the statement of the problem at the beginning of the topic and wrote my code. I got the expected rotation of the wave as a result.

```
{a, b, c, k, L, T} = {1, 10, 1, 1, 5, 2};
    u0[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2]/(2*Pi)
eq = D[u[t, x, y], t] == -k*y*D[u[t, x, y], x] + 
    D[a*y + b*Sin[x]*u[t, x, y] + c*D[u[t, x, y], y], y];
ic = u[0, x, y] == u0[x, y];
bc = {u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L], u[t, -Pi, y] == u[t, Pi, y]};
   sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, 
  u, {t, 0, T}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -L, L}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
plots = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[sol[t, x, y]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -L, L}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", 
    Mesh -> None], {t, 0, T, .05*T}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: The solution is perfect! Many thanks. Do you have any opinion on the mesh you use? I am not familiar with specifying these things.

Comment: I used a very simple option `Mesh -> None`

Comment: Sorry I must misunderstand. What I want to ask is Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}. How did you find those setup?

Comment: I solved a similar equation, only non-linear in the complex plane. I picked up the parameters experimentally.

Comment: Sorry.. I copy your code but I cannot reproduce your solution. If your ic is centered at origin, I guess it won't rotate, right?

Comment: Very sorry, I put the wrong parameters. Must be for this picture `{a, b, c, k, L, T} = {10, 10, 1, 1, 5, 2}`. Now I fixed the code.

Comment: I counted it again. For this picture `{a, b, c, k, L, T} = {1, 10, 1, 1, 5, 2}`

Comment: Thanks. Now it's fine.