# Solution distorsion after long time evolution for 2D+1 PDE

Tags: differential-equations

Continue the discussion [2D+1 PDE problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180104/unstable-solution-of-2d1-time-pde-with-periodic-boundary-condition?noredirect=1#comment471042_180104).

Why the solution eventually becomes messy and show those warning messages.

Here is the code:

```
a = 1;
T = 10;
ωcb = -50;
ωct = 50;
ωb = -5;
ωt = 5;
A = 10;
γ = 0.1;
kT = 0.1;
φ=π/4;
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

With[{u = u[t, θ, ω]}, 
  eq = D[u, t] == -D[ω u, θ] - D[-A Sin[θ] u, ω] - γ kT D[u, ω] + 1/10 D[ω u, ω];

  ic = u == EllipticTheta[3, (θ - φ)/2, E^(-a^2/2)]*
 E^(-ω^2/(2 a^2))/(2  π)^(3/2) /. t -> 0];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], u[t, θ, ωcb] == u[t, θ, ωct]}, 
    u, {t, 0, T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωcb, ωct}, 
    Method -> mol[50]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {24.137131, Null} *)

plots = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[ufun[t, θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, 
     PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    BoxRatios -> {Pi, ωb, 1}], {t, 0, T, .2}];
ListAnimate[plots]
```

[image: Time evolution]

It gives the following message:

```
NDSolveValue::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 6.689127286306131`.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {6.8,-3.14146,-4.9998} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {7.,-3.14146,-4.9998} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {7.2,-3.14146,-4.9998} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

How can this happen? I try to enlarge the MinPoints/MaxPoints, but it makes it worse. Any obvious mistake?

Would it related to the Courant condition? If the time step is too large, is there any thumb rule to better control it?

Comment: Your code doesn't run when pasted into a fresh session.  Could you check what's missing?  Anyhow, the messages give big clues to the problem.  The first one says `NDSolve` gave up at `t==6.689` because `MaxSteps` was reached.  The other messages indicate that evaluating the interpolating function after that point is based on extrapolation, hence the weird results.  Possible simple solution: add `MaxSteps->Infinity` to your `NDSolve`.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed a parameter φ=π/4;

Comment: I am wondering why mathematica can't treat this 2D+1 problem so well just like other problems.

Comment: Numerically solving PDEs is hard.  There are entire [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085164/good-textbook-in-numerical-pdes), [courses](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-920j-numerical-methods-for-partial-differential-equations-sma-5212-spring-2003/), and careers devoted to the subject.  Having done it manually, I'm amazed that Mathematica can do it at all.  Anyhow, it will sometimes need some guidance from the user as to appropriate numerical methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `MaxSteps->Infinity` to `NDSolveValue` fixes the problem.

```
Plot3D[Abs[ufun[T, θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, BoxRatios -> {Pi, ωb, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in my code. The function EllipticTheta[3, (0 - φ)/2, E^(-a^2/2)] should be instead  EllipticTheta[3, (θ - φ)/2, E^(-a^2/2)]. But your suggestion is perfect.

Comment: One question about the MaxStep. Does that mean my computation steps has already exceeded 10000?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `NDSolveValue::mxst` is saying.

Comment: And the program stop running in my original code, or?

Comment: I am still confused why as the time evolves, the computational effort will also increase and eventually kill the program. Is this a normal issue in PDE?

Comment: Yes, `NDSolveValue` stops at that point.  Look at the domain of `ufun` and you'll see it goes only to `t==6.689`.  When you `Plot3D` at larger times, the warning `InterpolatingFunction::dmval` tells you that the `t` value is outside the domain, so it can't be trusted.

Comment: If you want more solution, `NDSolve` will generally take more steps.  Just put `MaxSteps->Infinity` whenever you run into this problem.

Comment: Could you replace the EllipticTheta[3, (0 - φ)/2, E^(-a^2/2)]  to EllipticTheta[3, (θ - φ)/2, E^(-a^2/2)] , will you manage to obtain the solution?

Comment: I also found that the solution's amplitude is increasing. That's strange. Hmm...