# NDSolveValue gives an error that a list of equations is expected

Tags: differential-equations

I have this system of PDE that I want to solve. I reduced my original system of PDEs to the system below to capture the error (the actual code is after the image at the buttom):

[image]

Function `f1` does not depend on `r` explicitly and it has only value at `r = R`. In real problem `r` is the radius of a sphere and `f1` is some concentration at the surface of the sphere. If I delete the highlighted part there is no error. However, if I include the highlighted part I get this error and I do not know how to resolve it:

```
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {f1,NDSolve`xs$1041} cannot be transposed.
```

The code is here:

```
R = 2;

(*equations*)
eqns = {(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(f1[r, t]\)\) /. r -> R) == 
    f2[r, t] - 0.01*(f1[r, t] /. r -> R),
   \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(f2[r, t]\)\) == -1*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r, r\)]\(f2[r, t]\)\))
   };

(*initial condition*)
intis = {f1[r, 0] == 0, 
   f2[r, 0] == 0.1};

(*boundary condition*)
bc = {
   f2[R, t] ==  0.1,
   (Evaluate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(f2[r, t]\)\)] /. 
      r -> R) == (f1[r, t] /. r -> R)
   };

 (*solving the equations*)
{f1, f2} = 
 usol = NDSolveValue[
   Flatten[{eqns, intis, bc}], {f1, f2}, {r, 0.0, R}, {t, 0, 0.01}]
```

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. Try executing e.g. `y[x] /. x -> R == 0` and observe the output, and think about why you obtain this.

Comment: I corrected the assignment by using parenthesis `(y[x] /.x->R)  == 0` . However, now I get the error:
`Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {mT,mD,mB,mBG,NDSolve`xs$1044,NDSolve`xs$1043,NDSolve`xs$1045} cannot be transposed.` Here it seems something is wrong with the functions after `mGB`, but I cannot figure it out. Why the name of the functions in this list involve NDSolve?

Comment: Coding equations in this way makes them hard to check. I suggest using `With` like in e.g. [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180109/1871) to simplify the code.

Comment: Try `NDSolve` instead of `NDSolveValue`. Maybe you can fix that first. -- Minor style remark: I think `{f1, f2} = ...` is a bad idea, because then what were variables in `eqns` etc. now have values, making those previously defined things invalid.  It makes the code less robust, hard to play with and debug, imo.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What is the difference between `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue`?

Comment: In this case, the error messages printed.  I suspect the problem indicated by `NDSolve` is the critical one and perhaps causes the others messages in `NDSolveValue`.  I'm suggesting you look at the `NDSolve` message, which indicates the problem is ill-posed.  I don't know how to fix it, so I'm suggesting you might come up with an appropriate change. Alex Trounev basically guesses at a possible way to change the problem, which does in fact create a new problem that `NDSolve` will solve. But I don't know if the new problem is the one you want to solve or not.

Answer (score 1):

I debug the source code

```
R = 3.95; eps = 10^-3;
d2 = 0.03;
d3 = 11;
alpha1 = 0.2;
alpha2 = 0.12/60;
alpha3 = 1;
beta1 = 0.266;
beta2 = 0.28;
beta3 = 1;
gamma1 = 0.2667;
gamma2 = 0.35;
delta1 = 0.00297;
delta2 = 0.35;
 eq1 = {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(mT[r, theta, phi, 
      t]\)\) == (alpha1*mBG[r, theta, phi, t] + alpha2)*
             mD[r, theta, phi, t] - alpha3*mT[r, theta, phi, t] + 
           beta1*mBG[r, theta, phi, t]*cD[r, theta, phi, t] + 
           d2*(1./(R^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(mT[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\) + 1./(R^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(mT[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
                 1./R^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(mT[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\)),
      \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(mD[r, theta, phi, 
      t]\)\) == -(alpha1*mBG[r, theta, phi, t] + alpha2)*
             mD[r, theta, phi, t] + alpha3*mT[r, theta, phi, t] + 
           beta2*cD[r, theta, phi, t] - beta3*mD[r, theta, phi, t] + 
           d2*(1./(R^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(mD[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\) + 1./(R^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(mD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
                 1./R^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(mD[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\)),
      \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(mB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) == 
         gamma1*mT[r, theta, phi, t]*cB[r, theta, phi, t] - 
           gamma2*mB[r, theta, phi, t] - 
           delta1*mB[r, theta, phi, t]*cG[r, theta, phi, t] + 
           delta2*mBG[r, theta, phi, t] + 
     d2*(1./(R^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(mB[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\) + 1./(R^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(mB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
                 1./R^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(mB[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\)),
      \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(mBG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) == 
         delta1*mB[r, theta, phi, t]*cG[r, theta, phi, t] - 
           delta2*mBG[r, theta, phi, t] + 
     d2*(1./(R^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(mBG[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\) + 1./(R^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(mBG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
                 1./R^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(mBG[r, theta, phi, 
           t]\)\))};
   eq2 = {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) == 
        d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r, r\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              2./r*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) +
              1./(r^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\) + 1./(r^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              1./r^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\)),
      \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) == 
        d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r, r\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              2./r*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) +
              1./(r^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\) + 1./(r^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              1./r^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\)),
      \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) == 
        d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r, r\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              2./r*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) +
              1./(r^2*(Sin[phi])^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(theta, theta\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\) + 1./(r^2*Sin[phi])*Cos[phi]*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) + 
              1./r^2*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(phi, phi\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, 
          t]\)\))
      };
intis = {mT[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0, mD[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0, 
   mB[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0, mBG[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0, 
   cD[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0.001, cB[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0.001, 
   cG[r, theta, phi, 0] == 0.001};
bc = {mT[r, theta, eps, t] == 0.001, 
      mT[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      mT[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      mT[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      mD[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001,
      mD[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      mD[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      mD[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      mB[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001, 
      mB[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      mB[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      mB[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      mBG[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001,
      mBG[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      mBG[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      mBG[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      cD[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001, 
      cD[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      cD[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      cD[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      cD[R, theta, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cD[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) /. 
              r -> R) == (-(beta1*mBG[R, theta, phi, t] + beta2)*
              cD[R, theta, phi, t] + beta3*mD[R, theta, phi, t]),
      cB[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001,
      cB[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      cB[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      cB[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      cB[R, theta, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cB[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) /. 
              r -> R) == (-gamma1*mT[R, theta, phi, t]*
       cB[R, theta, phi, t] +
             gamma2*mB[R, theta, phi, t]),
      cG[r, theta, eps, t] ==  0.001,
      cG[r, theta, 2*Pi, t] == 0.001,
      cG[r, eps, phi, t] == 0.001,
      cG[r, Pi, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      cG[R, theta, phi, t] ==  0.001,
      d3*(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(cG[r, theta, phi, t]\)\) /. 
              r -> R) == (-delta1*mB[R, theta, phi, t]*
       cG[R, theta, phi, t] +
             delta2*mBG[R, theta, phi, t])
      };

usol = NDSolveValue[
  Flatten[{eq1, eq2, intis, bc}], {mT, mD, mB, mBG, cD, cB, cG}, {r, 
   eps, R}, {theta, eps, Pi}, {phi, eps, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 0.01}]

var = {mT, mD, mB, mBG, cD, cB, cG}; 
With[{r = R, t = .01}, 
  Table[Plot3D[
    usol[[i]][R, theta, phi, .01], {theta, eps, Pi}, {phi, eps, 2*Pi},
     PlotLabel -> var[[i]], PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue], {i, 1, Length[var]}]] // Quiet
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you. Could you please let me know what the problem was?

Comment: I have removed all `/.r->R` options so they are not required in this task.