# NDSolve Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions. However, all boundary conditions are defined

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the system of equations (momentum conservation, heat, and polymerization equations) in the [Couette problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couette_flow). There are two planes, the bottom is fixed, the top is moving with the speed 1. The bottom plane is heated with the temperature $T_0$, the top plane with $T_s$. At the initial time, I set a linear function for the velocity and the temperature, $0$ in the whole domain for the polymerization degree. Shortly, polymerization degree means the quality of curing of some polymer (for example, glue): $0$ means the "glue is fresh", $1$ means "glue is totally cured". Thus, $y$ always lays between $0$ and $1$.

Above process can be formulated by these system of equation:
$$\partial_t u=\partial_x(\mu(T,y)\partial_x u),$$ $$\qquad\partial_t T=\kappa\Delta T + H_{tr}\partial_t y,$$ $$\qquad\partial_t y= A(1-y)^n\exp(-E_a/T),$$
$$\mu(T,y)=\mu_0 \exp(E_\eta/T + \xi y)$$

The Wolfram Mathematica code is given as follows:

```
tmax = 10;
kappar = 0.8853475;
n = 1.2;
A = 120.9;
Ea = 8;
Eeta = 15.075;
Htr = 0.942895;
mu0 = 0.00213189;
ksi = 20;
T0 = 1; Ts = 400./300.;
mu[T_, y_] := mu0*Exp[Eeta/(T) + ksi*y];
mol[n_Integer, o_Integer] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> o, "Coordinates" -> N[Range[0, n]/n]}}
TinitLinear[x_] := T0 + (Ts - T0)*x;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
     D[mu[T[t, x], y[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], x], x], 
    D[T[t, x], t] == kappar*D[T[t, x], x, x] + Htr*D[y[t, x], t], 
    D[y[t, x], t] == ((1 - y[t, x])^n)*A*Exp[-Ea/(T[t, x])], 
    y[0, x] == 0., T[0, x] == TinitLinear[x], u[0, x] == x, 
    T[t, 0] == T0, T[t, 1] == Ts, u[t, 0] == 0., u[t, 1] == 1.}, {u, 
    T, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 5},
      "PDEDiscretization" -> mol[101, 4]}];
p1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u"}];
p2 = Plot3D[Evaluate[T[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "T"}];
p3 = Plot3D[Evaluate[y[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "\[Alpha]"}];
p4 = Plot3D[
   Evaluate[mu[T[t, x] /. sol, y[t, x] /. sol]], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 
    1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "\[Mu]"}];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

It gives the following error:
[image]

Why the wolfram gives me such a warning? I set up a bunch of boundary conditions:

- Since the system of equations is the first order in time, then I set up one initial condition per $u, T, y$,
- Since there is a second-order derivative in space ($u, T$), then I set up 2 Dirichlet boundary conditions
- Since the polymerization equation is ODE, then no need to set up boundary conditions in space

Could you give me a hint, where is the wrong logic? Or is it a wolfram `NDSolve` bug?
I searched similar problems in the StackExchange, but I found the cases where really insufficient boundary conditions: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73961/what-boundary-is-added-when-boundary-condition-is-not-sufficient),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188101/ndsolve-method-of-lines-unexpected-error-insufficient-boundary-conditions), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163793/automatic-boundary-conditions-in-ndsolve). In my case: I set up all boundary and initial conditions, and I still get a suspicious error.

## Update

I tried @xzczd's trick and set up the Dirichlet boundary condition:

```
y[t, 0] == 0
```

Such a trick get rid of the warning and mainly it gives a similar solution:
[image]

However,  at `t=10` and near `x=0`, the place where I enforced the boundary condition, the solutions diverges:
[image]

Also, I tried `y[t, 1] == 1` and it gives me similar poor results.

## Note

At big time $t\approx 20$ the polymerization degree $y(t,x)$ should approach 1. The approximate time can be estimated if you consider the isothermal case near corresponding walls with $T=T_s$ or $T=T_0$.
$$ \int_0^{y_*} \frac{dy}{(1-y)^n}=A\tau\exp(-E_a/T) = -\frac{(1-y_*)^{1-n} - 1}{1-n}$$

- If you take $y_*=0.5$, then you will get $\tau=2.5, 18.3$ for hot and cold walls,
- If you take $y_*=0.9$, then you will get $\tau=9.7, 72$ for hot and cold walls.

Comment: $\partial_x(\mu(T,y)\partial_x u)$ actually involves $\partial y/\partial x$, so you still need one b.c. for $y$.

Comment: Dear @xzczd, when I try to set up homogeneous neumann boundary  conditions for `y`: `Derivative[0, 1][y][t, 1] == 0`. I get an error: `NDSolve::bdord: Boundary condition (y^(0,1))[t,1] should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation.`

Comment: That's expected. For $\partial y/\partial x$ you can only set Dirichlet b.c.

Comment: @xzczd What does "For ∂y/∂x you can only set Dirichlet b.c. "? It is not physical to set Dirichlet b.c. for `y[t,x]` for both planes (`x=0` and `x=1`). Do you mean to define ∂y/∂x=0 at `x=0` and `x=1`? I have tried it at `x=1`: using ```Derivative[0, 1][y][t, 1] == 0```

Comment: As the warning said, "Boundary condition should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation." Just think about the simple $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - c\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$, if you set a Neumann b.c. for it, it'll generally lead to contradiction between b.c. and PDE. (Of course, there exist exceptions e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24417/1871), but that's another story. ) So, you need **one** Dirichlet b.c. for $y$ at either $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: To learn more about number of b.c., you may read: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450367/58219

Comment: @xzczd Partially I answered your suggestion (see my updated question). The warning is disappeared but setting up the Dirichlet boundary condition changes the original system of equations to a different system of equations. How to model Dirichlet b.c.?

Comment: That really depends on the underlying physics. Can you give a bit more background info? Is this PDE system from any literature? Or you deduced it yourself?

Comment: @EugeneW. How you know that at time t≈20 the polymerization degree $y(t,x)$ should approach 1?

Comment: Thank you for your question, I have added an explanation in my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using additional boundary condition for `y` and by increasing order of equation for `y` by differentiation $y_t$ on `x` as follows

```
    tmax = 10;
kappar = 0.8853475;
n = 1.2;
A = 120.9;
Ea = 8;
Eeta = 15.075;
Htr = 0.942895;
mu0 = 0.00213189;
ksi = 20;
T0 = 1; Ts = 400./300.;
mu[T_, y_] := mu0*Exp[Eeta/(T) + ksi*y];
mol[n_Integer, o_Integer] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> o, "Coordinates" -> N[Range[0, n]/n]}}
TinitLinear[x_] := T0 + (Ts - T0)*x;
```

Boundary condition for `y[t,x]` at `x=0`

```
sol0 = 
 DSolve[{y0'[t] == ((1 - y0[t])^n)*A*Exp[-Ea/(T0)], y0[0] == 0}, 
  y0[t], t];

sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
     D[mu[T[t, x], y[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], x], x], 
    D[T[t, x], t] == kappar*D[T[t, x], x, x] + Htr*D[y[t, x], t], 
    D[y[t, x], t, x] == D[((1 - y[t, x])^n)*A*Exp[-Ea/(T[t, x])], x], 
    y[0, x] == 0., y[t, 0] == y0[t] /. sol0[[1]], 
    T[0, x] == TinitLinear[x], u[0, x] == x, T[t, 0] == T0, 
    T[t, 1] == Ts, u[t, 0] == 0., u[t, 1] == 1.}, {u, T, y}, {t, 0, 
    tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> Automatic, 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> mol[137, 8]}];
```

Visualization (note, we use $\log_{10}\mu$)

```
p1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u"}, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
p2 = Plot3D[Evaluate[T[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "T"}, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
p3 = Plot3D[Evaluate[y[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "\[Alpha]"}, 
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
p4 = Plot3D[
   Evaluate[Log[10, mu[T[t, x] /. sol, y[t, x] /. sol]]], {t, 0, 
    tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Log\), \(10\)]\)\[Mu]"}, Mesh -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can compare `sol` with numerical solution computed with code @Eugene W.:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == 
     D[mu[T[t, x], y[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], x], x], 
    D[T[t, x], t] == kappar*D[T[t, x], x, x] + Htr*D[y[t, x], t], 
    D[y[t, x], t] == ((1 - y[t, x])^n)*A*Exp[-Ea/(T[t, x])], 
    y[0, x] == 0., T[0, x] == TinitLinear[x], u[0, x] == x, 
    T[t, 0] == T0, T[t, 1] == Ts, u[t, 0] == 0., u[t, 1] == 1.}, {u, 
    T, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> Automatic, 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> mol[137, 8]}];
```

In this case we have a message

```
NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.
```

Nevertheless both solutions are consider for every `t` and `x`

```
Table[{Plot[{y[t, x] /. sol, y[t, x] /. sol1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> t],
   Plot[{u[t, x] /. sol, u[t, x] /. sol1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> t, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[{T[t, x] /. sol, T[t, x] /. sol1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "T"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> t, 
   PlotRange -> All]}, {t, 1, 10, 3}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: It is an interesting trick, but such a boundary condition gives a totally different solution. If you see the equation for $y$, then you will see that at big time the solution $y$ approaches 1 in the whole domain.

Comment: @EugeneW. Do you mean that we need some additional equation for `y[t,0]`?

Comment: @EugeneW. Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! it is really a very smart trick! Thank you!

Comment: @EugeneW. You are welcome!