# Solving Burger's equation and continuity with a pressure forcing term for a gas

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

I'm trying to solve this Burger's equation and continuity with a pressure forcing term. Below is the code snippet that I've tried already for the non-dimensionalized equations. The parameter `B` is all of the constants wrapped up. I've tried a few methods like `ExplicitRungeKutta`, `StiffnessSwitching`, `BDF`, and `Automatic`, but the error I receive is always:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.4983101830020135`*^-16, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I don't really know how to fix this, so any help is appreciated!

```
BurgersAndContinuityEqns = 
  {r ne[r, t]* D[u[r, t],t] + ne[r, t] u[r, t] D[u[r, t]*r,r] == 
     -B D[r*ne[r, t], r], 
   r D[ne[r, t], r] + D[r u[r, t] ne[r, t], r] == 0, 
   u[r, ϵ] == 0, ne[r, ϵ] == Exp[-(r^2/2)]};
```

Here is the `NDSolve` snippet. I've tried putting the starting point off in time and space by machine epsilon, but no luck.

```
SolnBa =
esol = 
Block[{ϵ = $MachineEpsilon}, 
NDSolve[
BurgersAndContinuityEqns /. B -> 157.59, 
{u[r, t], ne[r, t]}, {r, ϵ, 5}, {t, ϵ, 0.18}, 
Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]]
```

Again, any help that can be provided is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the b.c. in $r$ direction? Notice you still need artificial b.c. representing infinity even if you're just solving an initial value problem. The "b.c." added automatically by `NDSolve` is almost always improper, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871) for more information.