# NDSolve: method of lines: unexpected error: insufficient boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, boundary-conditions, field-theory

As a test of my ability to master the Method of Lines I tried to `NDSolve` the PDE's system
$$\partial_t \varphi = \varpi\qquad\partial_t\varpi=\frac{1}{r}\partial^2_r(r\varphi)-\varphi$$
in the area
$$(t,r)\in[0,1]\times[0,1] $$
along with initial-boundary conditions 
$$ \varphi(0,r)=\cos(\pi r)\qquad \varpi(0,r)=\sin(\pi r)\qquad  \varpi(t,1)=0 $$

The problem is mathematically well posed:

1.Boundary condition $\varpi(t,1)=0$ implies $\varphi(t,1)=const.$

2.Initial data at $r=0$ should   evolve  in time just  as at any other point inside the sphere of radius $R=1$.

However my code

```
    rmax = 1; tmax = 1; e = 10^-21;
s = NDSolve[{D[φ[t, r], t] == p[t, r], 
    D[p[t, r], t] == D[r*φ[t, r], {r, 2}]/r - φ[t, r], 
    p[0, r] == Sin[ π*r/rmax], φ[0, r] == Cos[ π*r/rmax], 
    p[t, rmax] == 0}, {p, φ}, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, e, rmax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

results in the following error:

> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been 
>   specified for the direction of independent variable r. Artificial 
>   boundary effects may be present in the solution

How can I make Method of lines and *Mathematica* understand that boundary conditions are just fine?

PS: The equations above are the Klein-Gordon equations for  scalar field of mass $m=1$ in hamiltonian form and assuming spherical symmetry.

Comment: It produces a solution for me (the warning is just a warning).  Is the solution acceptable?

Comment: I was suggesting you could check...

Comment: The implication `\[CurlyPi][t, 1] == 0 \[DoubleRightArrow] \[CurlyPhi][t, 1] == const``is wrong!

Comment: $\varpi(t,1)=0\Rightarrow\partial_t\varphi(t,1)=0\Rightarrow \varphi(t,1)=\varphi(0,1)=\cos(\pi)=-1$

Comment: The problem is that "artificial boundary conditions" may modify the problem and then offer an acceptable solution but for the wrong problem.

Comment: Also I have not yet achieved an analytical solution so as to check the numerical one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need to introduce the intermediate variable $ \varpi$, `NDSolve` is clever enough to handle 2nd order derivative respects to $t$.
2. Though not necessary when analytically solving the problem, the boundary condition (b.c.) at $r=0$ is necessary for numeric solver, that's the reason why `bcart` warning pops up.
3. Don't trust the result when `bcart` pops up, for more information check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871).
4. Strictly speaking, there's an implicit b.c. called finiteness condition for this problem i.e. the solution is bounded in the domain, and the b.c. at $r=0$ can be deduced based on this condition.

OK, now let's fix your code. First simplify the code a little:

```
(* const is chosen casually because it's not given in the question. *)
const = -1;
With[{φ = φ[t, r]},
 eq = D[φ, t, t] == D[r φ, r, r]/r - φ;
 ic = {φ == Cos[π*r/rmax], D[φ, t] == Sin[π*r/rmax]} /. 
   t -> 0;
 bc@1 = φ == const /. r -> rmax;]
```

Then let's deduce the b.c. at $r=0$:

```
Clear@e;
bc@2 = Numerator@Together[Subtract @@ eq] == 0 /. r -> 0 /. h_[t, 0] :> h[t, e] // 
  Simplify
(* Derivative[0, 1][φ][t, e] == 0 *)
```

The last step is solving the problem, and we have 2 possible choices for spatial discretization. One is the default `"TensorProductGrid"` method:

```
mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

rmax = 1; tmax = 1; e = 10^-21;

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc@1, bc@2}, φ, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, e, rmax}, 
  Method -> Union[mol[100, 4], mol[True, 1]]]
```

Actually `mol[True, 1]` happens to be unnecessary for your specific b.c., but this option is often necessary when `ibcinc` warning pops up, for more information please check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

The other is the `"FiniteElement"` method:

```
solfem = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc@1}, φ, {t, 0, tmax}, {r, 0, rmax}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}]
```

Notice `"FiniteElement"` shows several advantages compared to `"TensorProductGrid"` in this case:

1. We can use $r=0$ as the left boundary because `"FiniteElement"` is able to handle the removable singularity there.
2. `bc@2` can be omitted because `0` Neumann value is the default setting of `FiniteElement`. For more information please check the **Details** of document of `NeumannValue`.
3. b.c. is imposed in a different way so we don't need to deal with the `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"` option.

Finally an illustration of the solution:

```
Plot3D[solfem[t, r], {t, 0, tmax}, {r, e, rmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Use of intermediate variable $\varpi$ is a matter of technique, not necessity.  The technical problem is that Mathematica should understand that boundary condition for $\varpi$ implies a boundary condition $\varphi$. So something is wrong with my code.

Comment: @dkstack Oops, I made a mistake in translating the b.c. at `r == rmax`. Now it's corrected. Notice the key point is b.c. at $r=0$ needs to be given explicitly when `TensorProductGrid` is chosen.