# Infinite expresssion 1/0 encountered when use NDSolve for 3D axisymmetric Navier-Stokes (Euler) equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, nonlinear, fluid-dynamics

The PDEs we are interested in solving using NDSolve is the vorticity-stream formulation of the 3D axisymmetric Navier-Stokes (Euler) equations (Ref.1 :T. Y. Hou, Potential singularity of the 3D Euler equations in the interior domain, arXiv:2107.05870):
\begin{equation}\label{NSvorticityStreamD2}
    u_{t}+(-xf_{z}) u_{x}+(2f+xf_{x}) u_{z}
    =\nu \left(u_{xx} +u_{zz}+\tfrac{3}{x}u_{x}\right) +2uf_{z}\\
    %
    w_{t}+(-xf_{z}) w_{x}+(2f+xf_{x}) w_{z}
    =\nu \left(w_{xx}+\omega_{zz}+\tfrac{3}{x}w_{x}\right)+2u u_{z},\\
    %
    -w=\,\,\,\,\left(f_{xx} +f_{zz}+\tfrac{3}{x}f_{x} \tag{1}\right).
\end{equation}

The initial conditions are
\begin{equation}\label{InitialConditions}
    u(0,x,z)=\frac{12000(1-x^2)^{18}\sin(2\pi z)}{1+12.5\sin^2(\pi z)},\\
    w(0,x,z)=f(0,x,z)=0 \tag{2}.
\end{equation}

The boundary conditions are
\begin{equation}\label{BoundaryConditionD2}
    u(t,\pm1,z)=f(t,\pm1,z)=w(t,\pm1,z)=0.\\
    u(t,x,\pm \tfrac12)=f(t,x,\pm \tfrac12)=w(t,x,\pm \tfrac12)=0.
\end{equation}

When I used the following NDSolve command

```
NDSolve[{PDE, IC, BC}, {u, w, f}, {t, 0, 1/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

I got the error message:

```
Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
```

I will add Mathematica code tonight.
Here is the Mathematica code:

```
PDE = {-2*u[t, x, z]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][t, x, z] + 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, z]*
      (2*f[t, x, z] + x*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, x, 
             z]) - x*Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][t, x, z]*
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, z] + 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, z] == 0, 
-2*u[t, x, z]*Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, z] + 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][w][t, x, z]*
      (2*f[t, x, z] + x*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, x, 
             z]) - x*Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][t, x, z]*
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][w][t, x, z] + 
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][w][t, x, z] == 0, 
w[t, x, z] + Derivative[0, 0, 2][f][t, x, z] + 
    (3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, x, z])/x + 
    Derivative[0, 2, 0][f][t, x, z] == 0}

IC = {w[0, x, z] == 0, f[0, x, z] == 0, 
 u[0, x, z] == 12000*(1 - x^2)^18*
     (Sin[2*Pi*z]/(1 + (25/2)*Sin[Pi*z]^2))}

BC = {w[t, x, 1/2] == 0, f[t, x, 1/2] == 0, 
 u[t, x, 1/2] == 0, w[t, x, -2^(-1)] == 0, 
 f[t, x, -2^(-1)] == 0, u[t, x, -2^(-1)] == 0, 
 w[t, 1, z] == 0, f[t, 1, z] == 0, u[t, 1, z] == 0, 
 w[t, -1, z] == 0, f[t, -1, z] == 0, 
 u[t, -1, z] == 0}

NDSolve[{PDE, IC, BC}, {u, w, f}, {t, 0, 1/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}]
```

From inspection, we know that if $u(0,x,z),w(0,x,z),f(0,x,z)$ are even in $x$, then the solution $u(t,x,z),w(t,x,z),f(t,x,z)$ will remain to be even in $x$. So the coordinate singular term $(1/x)u_x$ is nonsingular as $x\to 0$. NDSolve is not capable of figuring out this fact.

Any suggestions?

Best regards-
Mike

Comment: Having got what you wrote about the functions that are even in x I would still recommend replacing the terms like `(3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, x, z])/x` with `(3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][t, x, z])/Sqrt[x^2+eps]` where  `eps=0.00001` or so.  This alone does not solve your problem, since the warning: "Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy..." pops up.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: Thanks for your help. I replaced 1/x by 1/Sqrt[x^2+eps] and got error message: "Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both 
values and derivatives of the functions". After I specify the initial derivatives for all 3 dependent variables, I got error message :"Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve."

Comment: The latter message suggests that you use an older version of Mathematica, do you?

Comment: Using a spatial grid with an even number of points will avoid $x=0$ and perhaps have small error. Unfortunately, there is still the problem of finding initial conditions for all the variables (= functions & their derivatives). Perhaps you can do that by hand. (How to get an even number of points: `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 50, "MinPoints" -> 50}}`)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch you are right. with version 13.2, it is running now. By the way, because $-1<=x<=1$, I need to replace $1/x$ with Sign[x]/Sqrt[x^2+eps]$

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the suggestion.  For your option, the error message I got is "Because the coordinates were explicitly given for the direction of independent variable x, the values of options {MaxPoints, MinPoints, StartingPoints, MaxStepSize,MinStepSize,StartingStepSize} will be disregarded for this direction".

Comment: @mike, try changing `{x, -1, 0, 1}` to `{x, -1, 1}`.

Comment: @mike In the paper sited Thomas used adaptive mesh method proposed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.06663.pdf

Comment: @MichaelE2: I tried. It does not help. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Their adaptive mesh method looks too complicated to me.  I hope to take short cut with NDSolve. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this problem using implicit-explicit method and linear FEM as follows. First, we add artificial viscosity of about $10^{-6}$ so that $\nu\ne 0$. Note that artificial viscosity also used in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.05870.pdf) even Thomas Hou supposed $\nu=0$. Second, we use time step of about $dt=0.00005675$, while in the paper $dt\le 10^{-6}$. Third, our `mesh` is of 4050 quad elements only, while in the paper there is adaptive mesh by $1536\times 1536$ elements. Nevertheless we can reproduce singularity similar as in the paper.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-1, -1/2}, {1, 1/2}], 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005] ;
U[0][x_, z_] := 
 12000*(1 - x^2)^18*(Sin[2*Pi*z]/(1 + (25/2)*Sin[Pi*z]^2)); 
W[0][x_, z_] := 0; F[0][x_, z_] := 0;
nu = 10^-6; dt = 
 0.00227/40; T = {0.002271815, 0.002274596, 0.002276480};

Do[{U[i], W[i], F[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{(u[x, z] - U[i - 1][x, z])/dt - 
       x*Derivative[0, 1][F[i - 1]][x, z]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, z] + 
       Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 
         z]*(2*F[i - 1][x, z] + x*Derivative[1, 0][F[i - 1]][x, z]) - 
       2*u[x, z]*Derivative[0, 1][F[i - 1]][x, z] - 
       nu (Derivative[0, 2][u][x, z] + (3*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, z])/
           x + Derivative[2, 0][u][x, z]) == 
      0, -2*U[i - 1][x, z]*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, z] + 
       Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 
         z]*(2*F[i - 1][x, z] + x*Derivative[1, 0][F[i - 1]][x, z]) - 
       x*Derivative[0, 1][F[i - 1]][x, z]*
        Derivative[1, 0][w][x, z] + (w[x, z] - W[i - 1][x, z])/dt - 
       nu (Derivative[0, 2][w][x, z] + (3*Derivative[1, 0][w][x, z])/
           x + Derivative[2, 0][w][x, z]) == 0, 
     w[x, z] + (Derivative[0, 2][f][x, 
          z] + (3*Derivative[1, 0][f][x, z])/x + 
         Derivative[2, 0][f][x, z]) == 0, 
     DirichletCondition[{w[x, z] == 0, f[x, z] == 0, u[x, z] == 0}, 
      True]}, {u, w, f}, Element[{x, z}, mesh], 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, w -> 2, f -> 2}}];, {i, 1, 40}]
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[U[i][x, z], Element[{x, z}, mesh], PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLabel -> 1. dt i], {i,
   0, 40, 10}]

Table[Plot3D[W[i][x, z], Element[{x, z}, mesh], PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLabel -> 1. dt i], {i,
   10, 40, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

The detailed picture of singularity

```
{Plot3D[U[40][x, z], {x, 0, .04}, {z, 0, .04}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
 Plot3D[W[40][x, z], {x, 0, .04}, {z, 0, .04}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Very impressive! I would suggest that you publish it.  I do not quite understand that "Rectangle[{-1, -1/2}, {1, 1/2}]". The solutions are symmetric in $x$ and anti-symmetric in $z$.  I can follow you if you solve the PDEs for $-1<=x<=0,0<=z<=1/2$ and then symmetrize it wrt $x$ and anti-symmetrized wrt $z$.  But why "Rectangle[{-1, -1/2}, {1, 1/2}]"? What do is mean?

Comment: The thing people want to now is whether the singularity will form on the z axis (x=0) in finite time.  Thus the thing that is less ideal in Hou's paper, in my opinion, is that x=0 is the boundary of their simulation. This may introduce large error.  In my equations above, (x=0,z=0) is in the middle of the domain $D_2={(x,z): -1<=x<=1,-1/2<=z<=1/2}$, I was hoping to see that by putting the potential singular region in the middle of the simulation domain, we would see more accurate behavior of the solutions (finite time blowup singlarity formation)

Comment: @mike In your notation `Rectangle[{-1, -1/2}, {1, 1/2}]` is $D_2=(x, z): -1\le x\le 1, -1/2\le z \le 1/2$.

Comment: I see.  These are the lower-left and up-right corners.  Have you checked plots like "Plot[U[40][x, 0], {x, -0.05, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All]" and "Plot[U[40][x, 0], {x, -0.05, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All]"?  Why are they anti-symmetric in x?

Comment: @mike Actually this model defined at $x\ge 0$ only.  As I understand, solution at $x<0$ used for convergence only.

Comment: You are right.  Since doubling the domain in $x$ will not automatically reduce the error near $x=0$, I go back to original domain in Hou's paper $D=\{(x,z):0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq z\leq 1/2\}$. The solution looks similarly nice.  $1/x$ term will not cause trouble.

Comment: I also have question about DirichletCondition[{w[x, z] == 0, f[x, z] == 0, u[x, z] == 0}, True].  Is this an initial condition?  Why do we not need boundary conditions?

Comment: @mike `DirichletCondition[{w[x, z] == 0, f[x, z] == 0, u[x, z] == 0}, True]` are boundary conditions same as yours `BC`, while initial conditions are  `U[0][x_, z_] := 
 12000*(1 - x^2)^18*(Sin[2*Pi*z]/(1 + (25/2)*Sin[Pi*z]^2)); 
W[0][x_, z_] := 0; F[0][x_, z_] := 0;`.

Comment: Alex: How can I improve the quality of your NDSolve/FEM solution.  (1) set "MaxCellMeasure" to 0.0001 or even smaller; reduce dt to 1/10 of its original value and increase the total time steps tp 400.  Can I set "InterpolationOrder" to 4?  Best regards-

Comment: Actually the "MaxCellMeasure" and `dt` are only parameters to improve solution.

Comment: In the answer to question "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188101/ndsolve-method-of-lines-unexpected-error-insufficient-boundary-conditions", @xzczd mentioned that "We can use r=0 as the left boundary because "FiniteElement" is able to handle the removable singularity there". This probably explained why FEM worked here as well.

Comment: Hi Alex: I noticed an interesting difference between Thomas numerical solution in Ref.1 and your solution in the answer.  If you let $z1=4*10^{-3}} and do Plot[u[40][x,z1],{x,-0.02,0.02}], you will see that u[t(40)][x=0,z1]>1.  But from inspection of Figure (3.1) in Ref.1, you will see that |u[t(40)],x=0,z1)|<1/10.  This also true for w.  As you now that (Thomas)u1==(your)u, (Thomas)omega1==(your)w.

Comment: @mike Actually we can't reproduce results from Thomas paper one to one, since he used FDM, while we use FEM.