# A numerical boundary conditions paradox

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

For $(t,z)\in[0,1]\times[-1,0]$

```
zmin = -1; tmax = 1;
```

and some fields $w(t,z)$ and $y(t,z)$

```
n = 100; h = -zmin/(n-1);
W[t_] = Table[w[i][t], {i, n}]; 
Y[t_] = Table[y[i][t], {i, n}];
```

let there be the following PDE's system 
$$\partial_tw=\partial_zy+w\partial_zw$$
$$\partial_ty=\partial_zw+w\partial_zy$$

For the implementation of the Method of Lines derivatives $\partial_zw$ and $\partial_zy$ are numerically approximated as

```
Wz[t_] = Join[{(w[2][t] - w[1][t])/h}, 
Table[(w[i + 1][t] - w[i - 1][t])/(2h), {i, 2, n - 1}], {(
w[n][t] - w[n - 1][t])/h}];
```

and

```
Yz[t_] = Join[{(y[2][t] - y[1][t])/h}, 
Table[(y[i + 1][t] - y[i - 1][t])/(2h), {i, 2, n - 1}], {(
y[n][t] - y[n - 1][t])/h}];
```

Notice that the above  derivative formulas change  for $i=1$ (i.e. $z=-1$) and $i=100$  (i.e. $z=0$). This is a way to handle the fact that numerical integration for $z$ is confined in $[-1,0]$ and does not imply any boundary condition.

Then  the above PDE's system can be written as

```
wall[t_] = Yz[t] + W[t]*Wz[t];
eqw = Thread[
D[W[t], t] == wall[t] - PadLeft[{ wall[t][[n]]}, n]];
eqy = Thread[D[Y[t], t] == Wz[t] + W[t]*Yz[t]];
```

The only boundary condition that is implied by the above equations is that
$$w(t,0)=0$$ and this is the reason for the cumbersome statement of the dynamical equation for $w$ ( further explanation: press ctrl+F and type "here is the answer for point 3").

The boundary condition is accompanied by the following initial conditions

```
w0[z_] = -0.01*Sin[z*Pi]^2;
y0[z_] = 1;
initw = Thread[W[0] == Table[w0[zmin + (i-1)*h], {i, n}]];
inity = Thread[Y[0] == Table[y0[zmin + (i-1)*h], {i, n}]];
```

and then NDSolve is called to implement the method of lines

```
lines = NDSolveValue[{eqw, eqy, initw, inity}, {W[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 
tmax}];
```

So there arise the following questions:

1. Except $w(t,0)=0$ is there  any other boundary condition implicit in the finite difference equations? If it does  then which? If it doesn't then why does the code run? The problem seems underdetermined.
2. Can one call the Method of Lines as internal routine so as to increase the accuracy of the above code?

I am working on these but would appreciate any help.

Comment: 1. `h = -zmin/n` should be `h = -zmin/(n-1)`. 2. `/h, {i, 2, n - 1}]` should be `/(2h), {i, 2, n - 1}]`. 3. What's the meaning of `PadLeft[{ wall[t][[n]]}, n]`? If you think this will impose $w(t,0)=0$, you're wrong.

Comment: I believe that boundary conditions are needed for both `w` and `y`.  I am unaware of any way to call Method of Lines as internal routine, but you could use NDSolve directly to solve the coupled PDEs.

Comment: @xzczd here is the answer for point 3. `PadLeft[{ wall[t][[n]]}, n]` creates a list with n elements all of which is zero except the nth one that equals `wall[t][[n]]` . As a result the subtraction results in a list of n elements the first n-1 equal to `Yz[t] + W[t]*Wz[t]`  and the last one equal to zero. This means that $\partial_tw(t,0)=0$ and  results in $w(t,0)=w(0,0)=\sin(0)^2=0$.

Comment: @xzczd I edited my question according to point 2.

Comment: @bbgodfrey boundary condition about `y` concerns its value or could be stated in terms of its z-derivative? Also can you see why the code runs I mean if there is an implicit boundary condition in my code?

Comment: @xzczd concerning point 1. the choice `h=-zmin/n` results in a $z$-grid of $n$ points the $i=1$ point being $z=zmin+h$ and the $i=n$ point being $z=0$. So spatial integration is done for $z\in[-1+h,0]$ and not $[-1,0]$. I think this is not essential to the question but I will fix the code as soon as possible.

Comment: Oh… as to point3, you're right, I forgot about the i.c., but I think it's better to explain this a bit in the question. @bbgodfrey Have you read this post?: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28033/5331

Comment: @xzczd what do you think of point 1.? I mean is there any  difference between  `h = -zmin/n` and `h = -zmin/(n-1)` other than adding $h$ to the left end of $[-1,0]$?

Comment: There won't be any obvious difference when the grid is dense enough, of course. But it's just better to avoid this inaccuracy.

Comment: @xzczd I think it is ok now, what do you think?

Comment: @xzczd  Thanks for the link, which I had not seen.

Answer (score 4):

The solution you've observed is the artifact of 1st order one-sided difference formula

$$f' (x_n)\simeq \frac{- f (x_{n}-h)+ f (x_n)}{ h}$$

for approximating the PDE at the boundary. This can be confirmed by replacing it with 2nd order one-sided formula

$$f' (x_n)\simeq \frac{f (x_{n}-2h)-4 f (x_{n}-h)+3 f (x_n)}{2 h}$$

*If you're not familiar with one-sided formula, start from page 6 of [this book](https://disciplinas.stoa.usp.br/pluginfile.php/41896/mod_resource/content/1/LeVeque%20Finite%20Diff.pdf).*

```
zmin = -1; tmax = 1;

n = 100; h = -zmin/(n - 1);
W[t_] = Table[w[i][t], {i, n}]; 
Y[t_] = Table[y[i][t], {i, n}];


help[var_] := With[{w = var}, Join[{-{1, -4, 3}.{w[3][t], w[2][t], w[1][t]}/(2 h)}, 
   Table[(w[i + 1][t] - w[i - 1][t])/(2 h), {i, 2, 
     n - 1}], {{1, -4, 3}.{w[n - 2][t], w[n - 1][t], w[n][t]}/(2 h)}]]

Wz[t_] = help@w ;
Yz[t_] = help@y;


wall[t_] = Yz[t] + W[t]*Wz[t];
eqw = Thread[
   D[W[t], t] == wall[t] - PadLeft[{ wall[t][[n]]}, n]];
eqy = Thread[D[Y[t], t] == Wz[t] + W[t]*Yz[t]]; 

w0[z_] = -0.01 Sin[z π]^2;
y0[z_] = 1;
initw = Thread[W[0] == Table[w0[zmin + (i - 1)*h], {i, n}]];
inity = Thread[Y[0] == Table[y0[zmin + (i - 1)*h], {i, n}]];

lines = NDSolveValue[{eqw, eqy, initw, inity}, {W[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 
    tmax}];

{testw, testy} = 
 ListInterpolation[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@#[[0]]["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ # // 
     Transpose, {#[[1, 0]]["Coordinates"][[1]], Array[# &, n, {zmin, 0}]}] & /@ lines

Plot3D[testw[t, z], {t, 0, tmax}, {z, zmin, 0}, AxesLabel -> {t, z, f}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if we use 1st order one-sided formula instead:

```
help[var_] := With[{w = var}, Join[{(w[2][t] - w[1][t])/h}, 
   Table[(w[i + 1][t] - w[i - 1][t])/(2 h), {i, 2, n - 1}], {(
      w[n][t] - w[n - 1][t])/h}]]
```

The solution will be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference is obvious i.e. the solution depends on how we approximate the differential term at the boundary!

Further check by varying `n` shows both solutions are stable. This behavior never shows up when b.c. is enough AFAIK. For example, when dealing with the initial-boundary value problem

```
tend = 1/10; xl = 0; xr = 1;
With[{u = u[t, x]}, eq = D[u, t] == D[u, x, x];
 ic = u == Exp[-100 (x - (xl + xr)/2)^2] /. t -> 0;
 bc = {u == 0 /. x -> xl, D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> xr};]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, xl, xr}]
```

Both 1st and 2nd order approximation for the b.c. lead to the same solution, when the grid is dense enough:

```
Clear@dx
formula = eq /. {D[u[t, x], t] -> u[x]'[t], 
    D[u[t, x], x, x] -> (u[x - dx][t] - 2 u[x][t] + u[x + dx][t])/dx^2};

points = 25;
dx = (xr - xl)/(points - 1);
ode = Table[formula, {x, xl + dx, xr - dx, dx}];
odeic = Table[ic /. u[t_, x_] :> u[x][t] // Evaluate, {x, xl, xr, dx}];

bcnew1 = bc[[1]] /. u[t_, x_] :> u[x][t];

bcnew2 = bc[[2]] /. 
   D[u[t, x_], x_] :> (u[x - 2 dx][t] - 4 u[x - dx][t] + 3 u[x][t])/(2 dx);
bcnew3 = bc[[2]] /. D[u[t, x_], x_] :> (- u[x - dx][t] + u[x][t])/(dx);
mid[bc_] := (sollst = 
   NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, bcnew1, bc}, 
    u /@ Array[# &, points, {xl, xr}], {t, 0, tend}];
  ListInterpolation[
     Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ # // 
      Transpose, {#[[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]], Array[# &, points, {xl, xr}]}] &@sollst)
soltest1 = mid[bcnew2];
soltest2 = mid[bcnew3];
Manipulate[Plot[{soltest1[t, x], soltest2[t, x]}, {x, xl, xr}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Thick, Dashed}}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

OK, then how to explain this behavior? Is the difference formula actually equivalent to a hidden b.c.? This is exactly what I've asked in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871) and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28033/5331) post, but sadly nobody has found a satisfactory answer so far.

Comment: xzczd can you help me with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189109/ndsolve-method-of-lines-paradox-well-posed-ibvp-termed-undertedermined-when-t) question?

Comment: xzczd, what do you think of   this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189690/ibvp-mixing-temporal-and-spatial-derivatives-close-to-a-solution)? It may lead to a general method for first order IBVP problems that mix spatial and temporal derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

@bbgodfrey commented above that boundary conditions (b.c.) are needed for both $y$ and $w$. These b.c. can be time-independent, i.e. of the form $y_b=const.$ and $w_b=const.$ But it is reasonable that b.c. could be time-independent as well, i.e. of the form $y_b=y_b(t)$ and $w_b=w_b(t)$. Fuctions  $y_b(t)$ and $w_b(t)$ can have an analytic expression, but it is conceivable that this won't be always the case. They could be solutions of some differential equation that does not have any analytic solution.  And in particular, I think here comes the answer, functions   $y_b(t)$ and $w_b(t)$ could be solutions of the given PDE system.

In short I think that the code I posted gives a solution that by construction is characterised by b.c. $y(t,-1), y(t,0), w(t,-1)$ that are solutions of the PDE's system in question. These are complemented by b.c. $w(t,0)=0$ and together with initial conditions (i.c.) lead to a unique solution-the one to which  1st and 2nd order approximation mentioned by @xzczd converge as grid density increases.

I am not a methematician so I cannot be entirely sure that my answer is correct,though apparently reasonable. An expert's confirmation would be important.

Also if the answer is correct here comes the question if one can call method of lines as an internal routine and therefore avoid explicit discretization of the problem.

Comment: "In short I think that the code I posted gives a solution that by construction is characterised by b.c. $y(t,-1), y(t,0), w(t,-1)$ that are solutions of the PDE's system in question." Notice that given the highest differential order of $w$ and $y$ respect to $z$ is $1$, _usually_ you only need $2$ boundary conditions. (Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450367/58219) There exist more involved cases e.g. Inviscid Burgers equation though.

Comment: Ok then forget about $y(t,-1)$ and $ w(t,-1)$. My point is that the solution that occurs is not an artifact but a fare and square solution with b.c. that are time dependent, without any analytic expression, and which by construction are numerical solutions of the above PDE system.

Comment: Notice I've never denied that `lines` etc. are solutions for the PDE. I use the word "artifact" because those solutions aren't determined before a certain one-sided formula is chosen.

Comment: Yes but you have proven that any one-sided formula in the limit of very dense grid points to the same solution.

Comment: So we can reverse our logic and say: yes b.c. can be time dependent. Yes time dependent b.c. may be solutions of equations that do not have analytical solutions. And yes time dependent b.c. can be solutions of the specific PDE system we try to solve.

Comment: And then ask: how can we tell mathematica to integrate under such b.c.?

Comment: Simple answer: using the one sided derivative formula. Ask: which formula should I use? Say: All formulas point to the same answer in the limit of continuous grid.

Comment: The solution thus obtained is not trivial nor artificial. Is a certain solution with certain b.c.

Comment: "Yes but you have proven that any one-sided formula in the limit of very dense grid points to the same solution. " Only if the b.c. is enough. When b.c. is not enough like in your case, different one-sided formula leads to different solution.