# TemporalDiscretization in MethodOfLines

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, undocumented, finite-difference-method

When solving ODE's one can use options like `MaxStepFraction` to control the number of grid points.

When solving PDE's `SpatialDiscretization` option in `MethodOfLines` allows one to choose `MinPoints` for the spatial grid.

However there seem to be no such option as `TemporalDiscretization`.

How can one customize discretization along t-axis in `MethodOfLines` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still, it's `MaxStepSize`/`MaxStepFraction`.

If you give a single number as the option value of these options, that option value will be used for every dimension of the PDE.

If you give a number list whose length is the same as the number of independent variable of the PDE as the option value (yeah this syntax is undocumented but valid), the list of numbers will be used as the option values for corresponding dimension. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189770/1871) is an example.

All of the statement above can be verified by checking `"Coordinates"` of `InterpolatingFunction` generated by `NDSolve`. (If you don't know how to check, read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871). )

Nevertheless, notice that:

1. The initial value problem (IVP) solver of `NDSolve` is quite robust and we don't need to adjust time step choosing in most cases.
2. There's no `MinStepSize`/`MinStepFraction` option for `NDSolve` so we still need to adjust sub-option of `TensorProductGrid` if we need to control the spatial step size accurately.

Comment: So if I use `"MinPoints" -> 70`  along with `MaxStepFraction -> {Automatic, Automatic, 0.1}` then which option will be actually used by `NDSolve`? (I think `Automatic` corresponds to  `"MinPoints" -> 20` or `"MinPoints" -> 25`).

Comment: @jheidk51 `"MinPoints"`/`"MaxPoints"` will override `Automatic` of `MaxStepFraction`/`MaxStepSize`. You can verify this by checking `"Coordinates"` of the generated `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: @Harry As mentioned above, `MinStepSize` isn't an option for `NDSolve`. When being a sub-option of `TensorProductGrid`, it only controls spatial discretization. I think it's reasonable: the ODE solver is already self-adaptive, manually setting a `MinStepSize` for it will probably break the solver. If you really want to set a `MinStepSize` in `t` direction, I think your only choice is the `FixedStep` method.