# Problems with solving PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, functions, numerical-integration, constraint

I am using `NDSolve` to solve the two equations:

```
func[x_, t_] := ((v[x, t] - 9/100)*(1 + u[x, t]) - 1/2*u[x, t])/u[x, t];

equ = D[u[x, t], t] - 1/20*func[x, t] + D[u[x, t]^3*(D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]), x] == 0;
eqv = D[v[x, t], t] + u[x, t]^2/2*(3*D[u[x, t] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x])*D[v[x, t], x] - 1/10*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] == (1 - v[x, t])*(func[x, t]^2 - (1/10*Log[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])])^2);
```

with the parameters and trial code (it takes about 30s on my i5 laptop):

```
L = 10 \[Pi]; c = 1/40; v0 = 1/5; tmax = 200;
eqns = {equ, eqv, u[0, t] == u[L, t], v[0, t] == v[L, t], u[x, 0] == 1 + c*Cos[x], v[x, 0] == 1/10};    
{solnu, solnv} = NDSolveValue[eqns, {u, v}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

By plotting the solution, we found that after $t>100$, **the solutions begin to disappear partially** (see red lines for $t=101$):

```
Plot[{solnu[x, 0], solnu[x, 50], solnu[x, 100], solnu[x, 101]}, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 80,
Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.4, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{solnv[x, 0], solnv[x, 50], solnv[x, 100], solnv[x, 101]}, {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.4, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

**My thought:**

By evaluating the functions at a certain position, say, $x=4$, I can understand that the disappearance of the solutions is because the solutions become complex numbers as $t$ increases.

```
Table[solnu[4, tn], {tn, 0, tmax, 20}]

(*{0.983661, 0.894927, 0.873114, 0.859587, 0.853879, 0.828441, 
 0.729746 - 0.0799211 I, 0.291994 + 0.0356712 I, 0.170041 - 0.089365 I, 0.166466 - 0.0930112 I, 0.166531 - 0.0929651 I}*)

Table[solnv[4, tn], {tn, 0, tmax, 20}]

(*{0.1, 0.313017, 0.316713, 0.316615, 0.315822, 0.432728, 
 0.999884 - 0.000152834 I, 0.781819 - 0.00317719 I, 0.999983 - 5.23657*10^-6 I, 1. - 1.08127*10^-7 I, 1. - 6.74084*10^-8 I}*)
```

**In my problem, I need the solutions to be real over the entire domain.** I suspected that the solutions with the imaginary parts result from the last term, `Log[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])]`, of the 2nd equation, because the `Log` function itself has the domain of definition to be a real function. In addition, the function `v[x, t]` should not be larger than $1$, which is a physical constraint. See also the lower fig, the curves of `solnv` begin to vanish as the peak approaches to $1$).

**My first question is:**

Is it possible to add a physical constraint of `0<v[x, t]<=vlim[x,t]` in the code to make the solution reasonable? Here, `vlim[x, t]` is determined by the solutions:

```
vlim[x_, t_] := Exp[4800*(1/350 - solnu[x, t]/((solnv[x, t] - 1/10)*solnu[x, t]))];
```

Or, is it acceptable if I only take the solutions before they vanish (i.e. $t\le 100$). In other words, is it equivalent to the constraint if one only takes the solutions from the current code, which still satisfy the constraint (e.g. by checking `v[x, t]`)?

If you think there is something wrong with my idea, please also leave your comments and suggestion.

**My second problem (solved by @Alx):**

By defining a function based on the solutions, I need to numerically integrate the function at a given time, say, $t=50$. But `NIntegrate` runs for a very long time ... (aborted by myself). Please help me with defining such a function and then `NIntegrate` it correctly. Thank you in advance!

```
funcSol[x_, t_] := ((solnv[x, t] - 1/10)*(1 + solnu[x, t]) - solnu[x, t])/solnu[x, t];

NIntegrate[funcSol[x, 50], {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: For the second problem use `funcSol[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ]:= ...` so that `NIntegrate` will get numerical input as it expects.

Comment: Is there reason to believe that the exact solution actually is real over the entire domain?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes, both solutions u and v should be real because they are for real physical quantities. The problem is how to add the constraint in my **first question**. Thank you.

Comment: Physically, how close to `1` can `v` become?

Comment: @user55777 From a physical point of view you should use `Log[Abs[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])]]`

Comment: @user55777 Explain what this model describes. Then I will explain to you why there should be `Log[Abs[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])]]`

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the question, the computation fails when `v[x, t] >= 1`.  This is easy to fix by replacing `(1 - v[x, t])` by `Max[1 - v[x, t], 10^-8]` in the right side of `eqv`.  (Results below do not change, if `10^-8` is replaced by `10^-6`.)  For completeness, here is a plot of the problem term.  It is not large in value.

```
Plot[(1 - z)*(-(1/10*Log[(1 - v0)/(1 - z)])^2), {z, 0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {v, Null}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}]
```

[image]

However, the solution still behaves badly for `t` greater than about `100`.  Examining the details of these solutions suggests that the default value of `MaxStepFraction` is too large to  resolve sharp variations in the solution.  So, I steadily decreased`MaxStepFraction` until the computations proceeded stably at least as far as `t == tmax`.  This required `MaxStepFraction -> 1/1000`, which led to solution plots,

```
Plot3D[solnu[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}, 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200]
Plot3D[solnv[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, v}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

[image]

A phase transition appears to occur at about `t == 140`.  A computation with `MaxStepFraction -> 1/2000` produced similar plots, but with the transition at about `t == 120`.

**Addendum: 1D solution**

One might expect that setting `c = 0` would yield a solution independent of `x`.

```
L = 10 \[Pi]; c = 0; v0 = 1/5; tmax = 200;
eqns = {equ, eqv, u[0, t] == u[L, t], v[0, t] == v[L, t], u[x, 0] == 1 + c*Cos[x], 
    v[x, 0] == 1/10, WhenEvent[Max@Table[v[L (i - 1/2)/7, t], {i, 7}] > 2/5, 
    tend = t; "StopIntegration"]};
{solnu, solnv} = NDSolveValue[eqns, {u, v}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    MaxStepFraction -> 1/4000]
```

where `WhenEvent` is used to stop the integration when `v[x, t]` starts growing toward `1`, as now requested in the question.  Doing so saves a lot of run time too.  The resulting plots, similar to those above but cut off at `tend = 126.977`, are

[image]

[image]

Evidently, these oscillations are growing from truncation errors and do not yield a 1D solution.  A true 1D solution is obtained by explicitly eliminating x-dependence from the equations.

```
func[x_, t_] = (((v[x, t] - 9/100)*(1 + u[x, t]) - 1/2*u[x, t])/u[x, t]) 
    /. {u[x, t] -> u[t], v[x, t] -> v[t]};
equ = Unevaluated[D[u[x, t], t] - 1/20*func[x, t] + D[u[x, t]^3*(D[u[x, t], x] 
    + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]), x] == 0] /. {u[x, t] -> u[t], v[x, t] -> v[t]};
eqv = Unevaluated[D[v[x, t], t] + u[x, t]^2/2*(3*D[u[x, t] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x])*
    D[v[x, t], x] - 1/10*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] == (1 - v[x, t])*(func[x, t]^2 - 
    (1/10*Log[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])])^2)] /. {u[x, t] -> u[t], v[x, t] -> v[t]};

v0 = 1/5; tmax = 5 10^4;
eqns = {equ, eqv, u[0] == 1, v[0] == 1/10};
{solnu, solnv} = NDSolveValue[eqns, {u, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxStepSize -> 10^-2]

Plot[solnu[t], {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {t, u}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[solnv[t], {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {t, v}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All]
{solnu[tmax], solnv[tmax]}
```

[image]

[image]

```
(* {0.287336, 0.201601} *)
```

which is very close to the symbolic asymptotic solution, `{(9 - 100 v0)/(-59 + 100 v0), v0}`.  With `v0 = 0.2`, these are

```
(* {0.282051, 0.2} *)
```

We see from the last two plots that the asymptotic solution is not achieved for `tmax` less than about `10^4`, much larger than `tmax` achievable for the 2D computations.  The robustness and relatively long wavelength of the growing 2D oscillations cause me to wonder whether there is an error in the spatial derivative terms of the PDEs.

Comment: Perhaps you can adjust temperal grid and spatial grid separately using e.g. `MaxStepFraction -> {1/30, 1/1000}`? (More discussion can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204761/1871). )

Comment: @xzczd  I am aware of this capability, but the variation in `x` and in `t` both are extreme.

Comment: @user55777 The solution rapidly reaches a steady state but apparently becomes numerically unstable at much later time.

Comment: @bbgodfrey when observing `u` we can see its peaks increase in time near tmax, why did you say the solution reaches a steady state rapidly? Could you update by adding some descriptions?

Comment: @user55777  It reaches a steady state at around `t == 50` but goes unstable at around `t  == 100`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey could you show by plotting that it reaches such a steady state?

Comment: @user55777  I was mistaken.  The 2D solution does not come close to reaching steady state, as can be seen by solving the 1D problem numerically.  (The symbolic staty state in 1D is `u == 11/39`, `v == 1/5`.)  Are you sure that the spatial derivative terms in the 2D equations are correct?

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry for the late reply. I need time to go through all the reply. Btw, fig.1 is *a plot of the problem term*, which term did you refer to? Did you mean `1 - v[x, t]`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey "...MaxStepFraction is too **small** to resolve sharp variations in the solution." I always supposed that it is a too **big** `MaxStepFraction` that fails to resolve sharp variations in the solution. Please give me some advice.

Comment: @user55777  I was careless in my choice of words.  I did mean "too big".  I also added the code that created the first plot.

Comment: @bbgodfrey "replacing `(1 - v[x, t])` by `Max[1 - v[x, t], 10^-8]` in the right side of eqv"... did you replace both two terms on rhs?

Comment: @user55777  Yes, I did.  However, if `WhenEvent` is used to terminate the computation before it reaches `v == 1`, as I did for the fourth and fifth plots, then using `Max` is unnecessary.  By the way, I have some new ideas for investigating the issues here, but I will not have time to do so for a few days.

Comment: @bbgodfrey many thanks for your valuable time. I understand that you stop the integration by monitoring the max among 7 x-positions of `v`. Well, is there any special reason for choosing the criterion `2/5` in the event `Max@Table[v[L (i - 1/2)/7, t], {i, 7}] > 2/5`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey for the 1D solution from the constant initial conditions, you said that "these oscillations are growing from truncation errors". I guess they could grow from the instabilities described by the equation. Am I right?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Very impressive. By eliminating x-dependency, you obtained the "asymptotic solution". What did you mean by asymptotic solution here? Do you think that if the 2D eqns have a steady state, it should be (close to) the asymptotic soln after the same order of transition time as in the 1D soln?

Comment: @user55777  I chose `2/5`, because it was somewhat larger than the value of v for the initial plateau but still much less than `1`.  By asymptotic, I meant steady state.  The oscillations could be from a physical instability, but they still have to start from some irregularity in `x`.  Because they grow even with `c = 0`, the only source left is numerical noise.  Thanks for checking the spatial derivative terms.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you for the suggestions! What is the relation between the 1D and 2D solutions? Does the steady state of 1D solution imply that 2D solution should also reach a steady state under instabilities governed by the x-dependent terms? In other words, if those terms are destabilizing/stabilizing effects the 2D solution will reach a steady state more slow/quickly compared to that of 1D solution. So the existing numerical instability is due to the not-that-good spatial discretization?

Comment: The first thing to check is whether the equilibrium described near the end of my answer is stable.  Do this by linearizing the equations about this equilibrium.  Then, Fourier-transform the linearized equations in `x` Laplace-transform them in `t`, and determine whether the resulting eigensystem has exponentially growing modes in `t`.  If so, the equilibrium is unstable, and numerical solutions always will blow up in time.  If the equilibrium is stable, on  the other hand, then the numerical method used by `NDSolve` must be unstable, and attention should be given to finding a stable algorithm.

Comment: @user55777  "symbolic asymptotic solution, {(9 - 100 v0)/(-59 + 100 v0), v0}"

Answer (score 1):

For such a system of nonlinear equations it is necessary to use a special method of solution and a thin grid with a sufficiently large number of cells. Then the concentration function will be automatically limited and the solution will look completely different than on a coarse grid of 25 cells, which is used in the automatic solution method.

```
func[x_, t_] := ((v[x, t] - 9/100)*(1 + u[x, t]) - 1/2*u[x, t])/
   u[x, t];

equ = D[u[x, t], t] - 1/20*func[x, t] + 
    D[u[x, t]^3*(D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]), x] == 0;
eqv = D[v[x, t], t] + 
    u[x, t]^2/2*(3*D[u[x, t] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x])*
     D[v[x, t], x] - 
    1/10*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] == (1 - 
      v[x, t])*(func[x, 
        t]^2 - (1/10*Log[Abs[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])]])^2);

L = 10 \[Pi]; c = 1/40; v0 = 1/5; tmax = 200;
eqns = {equ, eqv, u[0, t] == u[L, t], v[0, t] == v[L, t], 
   u[x, 0] == 1 + c*Cos[x], v[x, 0] == 1/10};
{solnu, solnv} = 
 NDSolveValue[eqns, {u, v}, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 137, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]

Plot[{solnu[x, 0], solnu[x, 50], solnu[x, 100], solnu[x, 101]}, {x, 0,
   L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 80,
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Blue, Red}]

Plot[{solnv[x, 0], solnv[x, 50], solnv[x, 100], solnv[x, 101]}, {x, 0,
   L}, PlotRange -> {{0, L}, All}, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Green, Blue, Red}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
{Plot3D[solnu[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[solnv[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

This method can be used up to `t=270` without loss of stability, but without violation of condition `v<1` only up to `t=230`. The result is similar to what @bbgodfrey got.

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Using `Pseudospectral` does delay the onset of rapidly growing oscillations a bit but it does not eliminate them.  In fact, to reach the steady state that the OP apparently wants would require `tmax` of order `10,000`!  The robustness and relatively long wavelength of these growing oscillations cause me to wonder whether there is an error in the spatial derivative terms of the PDEs.

Comment: I agree that in this case the instability is suppressed at `t<200`, but grows rapidly at `t>250`. Consequently we still need to limit the concentration. Obviously, the model is unsuitable for modeling real effects.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be 4th one I find in this site, on which the default spatial discretization of `NDSolve` doesn't work well even if nothing like [shock wave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11748/1871) involves in. (BTW here are [1st one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133315/1871), [2nd one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180897/1871) and  [3rd one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182050/1871). )

The following method gives stable solution up to `tmax = 200`. The key point is the discretization of `D[u[x, t]^3 (D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]), x]` in `equ`. We need to discretize it before the automatic symbolic differentiation happens. In other words, terms like $\frac{\partial (f g)}{\partial x}$ should be discretized as

$$\frac{\partial (f g)}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=x_i} \approx  \frac{f(x_i+h) g(x_i+h)-f(x_i-h)g(x_i-h)}{2h}$$

Notice this scheme is different from:

$$\frac{\partial (f g)}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=x_i}=\left(f\frac{\partial  g}{\partial x}+g\frac{\partial  f}{\partial x}\right)\Biggl|_{x=x_i}\approx f(x_i) \frac{g(x_i+h)-g(x_i-h)}{2h}+g(x_i)\frac{f(x_i+h)-f(x_i-h)}{2h}$$

I'll use [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for discretization, notice the periodic b.c.s are set by 5th argument of `pdetoode`:

```
func[x_, t_] := ((v[x, t] - 9/100) (1 + u[x, t]) - 1/2 u[x, t])/u[x, t];

equ = D[u[x, t], t] - 1/20 func[x, t] + D[mid[x, t], x] == 0;
midexpr = u[x, t]^3 (D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}]);

eqv = D[v[x, t], t] + u[x, t]^2/2 (3 D[u[x, t] + D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x]) D[v[x, t], x] - 
    1/10 D[v[x, t], {x, 2}] == (1 - 
      v[x, t]) (func[x, t]^2 - (1/10 Log[(1 - v0)/(1 - v[x, t])])^2);


L = 10 π; c = 1/40; v0 = 1/5; tmax = 200;

ic = {u[x, 0] == 1 + c*Cos[x], v[x, 0] == 1/10};

points = 300; difforder = 2; domain = {0, L}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];

(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post, 
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{u, v, mid}[x, t], t, grid, difforder, True];

rule = Thread[ptoofunc@mid[x, t] -> ptoofunc@midexpr];
ode = ptoofunc@{equ, eqv} /. rule;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic}, Outer[#@#2 &, {u, v}, grid], {t, 0, tmax}(*,
   Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}*)]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.0083, Null} *)
{solu, solv} = rebuild[#, grid, -1] & /@ sollst

With[{solnu = solu, solnv = solv}, 
 Plot3D[solnu[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]]
```

[image]

```
With[{solnu = solu, solnv = solv}, 
 Plot3D[solnv[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, v}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

You may have noticed it's not necessary to modify the `Log[…]` term in `eqv` with this method.

Unfortunately, for larger `tmax` e.g. `tmax = 300`, the method still becomes unstable, perhaps a even better difference scheme helps, but I haven't found any so far.

Comment: it seems that you never use the boundary conditions?

Comment: @user55777 Periodic b.c. is set by 5th argument of `pdetoode`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I need time to understand the method. Btw, when using a spline ic: `iniu[x_] = 1 + c*BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20], SplineClosed -> True][x/L];` I got the error "Initial condition is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers", even I set its attribute with `SetAttributes[iniu0, Listable];` and used `iniu0[x_] = iniu[x];` in `ic = {u[x, 0] == iniu0[x], v[x, 0]...};`? Please give some suggestion.

Comment: @user55777 Just check what's inside your `ic`, and re-visit how I make use of `Listable`.

Comment: it is `ic = {u[x, 0] == iniu[x], v[x, 0] == 1/10}`, where `iniu[x]` is a spline function. Sorry, i cannot really understand your question. But I understood that we should add `Listable` to the list of attributes of the symbol `iniu`, as you did.

Comment: @user55777 No, it's not. Check `OwnValues@ic`.

Comment: it seems that `ic` is not yet to be applied due to `RuleDelayed`? But I am not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98537/discussion-between-xzczd-and-user55777).