# Nonlinear dispersal equation modeling insect aggregation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, ecology

I'm a newbie with *Mathematica*, I know it's a basic answer, but I can't solve the problem on my own.

I have the following equation reflecting insect aggregation at low population densities (taken from page 404 of *J.D. Murray*'s [*Mathematical Biology:
I. An Introduction, Third Edition*](http://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files/27f6eba850c27d335ff3f93778d8057f.pdf)):

$$\partial_t u = \partial_x (\text{sign}(x) u) + \partial_x (u^2\partial_x u)$$
with initial condition
$$u(x,0)= e^{-x^2}$$
and boundary conditions
$$u(-7,t)=u(7,t)=0$$

and I want to integrate it until time $t=2$. I obtain the following plot with a program I did with Python, but I have no idea if my solution is correct, so I'd like to double check it with Mathematica.

[image]

I tried the following snippet:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[x, t], t] == D[Sign[x]*u[x,t],x] + D[u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x], x],
   u[-7, t] == 0, u[7, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]}
  , u, {x, -7, 7}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

but `NDSolve` spits out `NDSolveValue::ndnum` warning and fails. Can someone confirm I wrote the right snippet and show the plot I should obtain?

---

**EDIT:**

After a check on my Python implementation, here's what I found at $t=2$:

[image]

As pointed out by @xzczd, using a finer mesh can help:

[image]

Comment: `sign` is not a built-in function of _Mathematica_, I think you mean `Sign`, but it's not differentiable at $x=0$, so we need a bit extra work to define a differentiable `sign` ourselves. Then, are you sure the equation itself is correct? The solution blows up very fast.

Comment: @xzczd I edited with `Sign. Yes, the PDE it's taken from Murray's book (1 volume), page 404. I just have to choose boundary  and initial conditions, so I chose those ones, which are compatible.

Comment: You could replace `Sign` with `Tanh[1000 x]` or `2 ArcTan[100 x]/Pi` which are close to a Sign function. The plot then works, but only for very small values of t near zero. By the time t=0.04 the solution is already a mess.

Comment: @flinty If the equation is correct, then this is another example that special spatial discretization is needed. See my answer below for more info.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/35955/5331

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the equation is correct, then it's probably another example that we need special treatment for the discretization of [conservation law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law#Differential_forms).

As mentioned in the comment above, one easy-to-notice issue of OP's trial is `Sign[x]` isn't differentiable at `x == 0`. This seems to be easy to resolve: we just need to define a differentiable approximate sign ourselves:

```
appro = With[{k = 100}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];

sign[x_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand[Sign[x], Reals] /. UnitStep -> appro
```

Nevertheless, it just leads to a solution messing up quickly:

```
soltest = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] == 
    D[sign[x]*u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x], x], u[-7, t] == 0, u[7, t] == 0, 
   u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]}, u, {x, -7, 7}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz At t == 0.25352360860722767`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

> NDSolveValue::eerr

Does this suggest the equation itself is wrong? Not necessarily, because the PDE involves differential form of consevation law, and we already have several examples showing that serious problem may come up if spatial discretization isn't done properly on such type of PDE:

[Conservation of area solving a PDE via finite difference scheme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128447/1871)

[Instability, Courant Condition and Robustness about solving 2D+1 PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180834/1871)

[How to solve the tsunami model and animate the shallow water wave?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107988/1871)

[Problems with solving PDEs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/205003/1871)

So, how to resolve the problem? If you've read the answers above, you'll notice the most effective and general solution seems to be avoiding the symbolic calculation of outermost `D` before discretization, and I've figured out 3 ways to.

Additionally, a method that doesn't require one to transform the equation is found, but this only works in or before *v11.2*.

### `FiniteElement` Based Solution

Thanks to the new-in-*v12* nonlinear `FiniteElement` method, it's possible to resolve the problem completely inside `NDSolve` with the help of `Inactive`:

```
With[{u = u[x, t]}, 
 neweq = D[u, t] == 
   Inactive[Div][{{Sign[x] u/D[u, x] + u^2}}. Inactive[Grad][u, {x}], {x}]]

{bc, ic} = {{u[-7, t] == 0, u[7, t] == 0}, u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]}

solFEM = NDSolveValue[{neweq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -7, 7}, 
  Method -> {MethodOfLines, 
    SpatialDiscretization -> {FiniteElement, MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1}}]

p1 = Plot[solFEM[x, 2], {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Several warnings will pop up, but don't worry.

Tested on *v12.0.0*, *v12.1.1*.

### Semi-`NDSolve` Based Solution

You may be suspicious of the result above because it's different from your first one. Also, you may find `NDSolveValue` fail for certain setting of `MaxCellMeasure` (say `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01`), which seems to make the result more suspicious, so let's double check it with another method i.e. a self-implementation of method of lines, as I've done in answers linked above.

I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the discretization in $x$ direction.

```
domain = {L, R} = {-7, 7}; tend = 2;
With[{u = u[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]}, eq = {D[u, t] == D[mid, x],
   mid == Sign[x] u + u^2 D[u, x]};
 {bc, ic} = {u == 0 /. {{x -> L}, {x -> R}}, u == Exp[-x^2] /. t -> 0};]

points = 100;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{u, mid}[x, t], t, grid, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

Block[{mid}, Evaluate@ptoofunc@eq[[2, 1]] = ptoofunc@eq[[2, -1]]; 
  ode = ptoofunc@eq[[1]] // del];
odeic = ptoofunc[ic] // del;
odebc = ptoofunc[bc];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odebc, odeic}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}];
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid, 2]

p2 = Plot[sol[x, tend], {x, L, R}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image]

Tested on *v9.0.1*, *v12.0.0*, *v12.1.1*.

### `TensorProductGrid` Based Solution

It's a bit surprising that the following method even work in *v9*, because `pdord` is just equivalent to failure in my memory:

```
{L, R} = {-7, 7}; tend = 2;

With[{u = u[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]},
 eq = {D[u, t] == D[mid, x], mid == Sign[x] u + u^(2) D[u, x]};
 {bc, ic} = {u == 0 /. {{x -> L}, {x -> R}}, u == Exp[-x^2] /. t -> 0};]

icadditional = mid[x, 0] == eq[[2, 2]] /. u -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@ic[[2]]]

solTPG = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc, icadditional}, {u, mid}, {t, 0, tend}, {x, L, R}, 
  Method -> {MethodOfLines, 
    SpatialDiscretization -> {TensorProductGrid, MaxPoints -> 500}}]

p3 = Plot[solTPG[[1]][x, 2], {x, L, R}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thin}]
```

[image]

Again, you'll see several warnings, simply ignore them.

Tested on *v9.0.1*, *11.3.0*, *v12.0.0*, *v12.1.1*.

### `fix` Based Solution (Only Works Before *v11.3*)

Luckily, my [`fix`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129193/1871) turns out to be effective on the problem. If you're in or before *v11.2*, then this is probably the simplest solution (but as you can see, it's not quite economical, `2000` grid points are used to obtain a good enough result):

```
appro = With[{k = 100}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];

sign[x_] = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand[Sign[x], Reals] /. UnitStep -> appro

solpreV112 = 
 fix[tend, 4]@
  NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[sign[x] u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x], x], 
    u[-7, t] == 0, u[7, t] == 0, u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]}, u, {x, -7, 7}, {t, 0, 2}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 2000, 
       "MinPoints" -> 2000, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]

Plot[solpreV112[x, tend], {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Tested on *v9.0.1*.

The 4 solutions agree well. Your first result in Python is wrong.

### Remark

If you want to check the $m=\frac{1}{2}$ case mentioned in p404 of the book, remember to add a `Re` to the code to avoid tiny imaginary number generated by numeric error. To be more specific, you need to use

```
With[{u = u[x, t]}, 
 neweq = D[u, t] == 
   Inactive[Div][{{Sign[x] u/D[u, x] + Re[u^(1/2)]}}. Inactive[Grad][u, {x}], {x}]]
```

in the `FiniteElement` based approach,

```
With[{u = u[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]}, eq = {D[u, t] == D[mid, x],
    mid == Sign[x] u + Re[u^(1/2)] D[u, x]};]
```

in the semi-`NDSolve` based and `TensorProductGrid` based approach, and

```
Plot[solpreV112[x, tend] // Re, {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

in the `fix` based approach. (Yeah in `fix` approach you just need to add `Re` into `Plot`. )

BTW the obtained result seems to be consistent with the one in the book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I indeed used a finite element approach (with degree one) in my Python code, so there must be something wrong in my implementation, or should I expect that a FEM approach fails because the one of Mathematica has something special? @xzczd

Comment: I just edited my post with what I obtain with FEM (with degree 1 elements), this seems right now. How do you think one can remove oscillations?

Comment: @Vefhug Using a denser mesh should help. (Given that you're using degree 1 element, the mesh may need to be quite dense. )

Comment: @xzcdz thanks, that's right. Since oscillations appear also in Mathematica, it should be a problem of these method itself, due to the non-differentiability of $\text{sgn(x)}$. Btw, why do you state that my result Python in "wrong". It seems that same of Mathematica, actually.

Comment: @Vefhug That line is written before your **EDIT**.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. I wrote a last edit wher I show the effects of the refinement. Thanks for your detailed answer! I try not to use Mathematica as much as I can because I prefer to write my own code (I'm still a student), but it's indeed really good software @xzczd

Comment: With your answers now I'm fine with those kind of equations, thanks. I just asked a last question, this time about Schroedinger equation, which I think it's too hard to do with Mathematica (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231470/time-dependent-schroedinger-equation-in-2d)

Comment: @Vefhug As shown by Henrik, it's quite straightforward to solve the problem in _Mathematica_, why do you think it's too hard?

Answer (score 5):

If only the steady state is desired, it can be obtained easily by

```
sa = Values[DSolve[1 + u[x] D[u[x], x] == 0, u[x], x] /. C[1] -> c][[2, 1]]
```

and `c` determined from conservation of the the integral over `u`.

```
scint = Integrate[sa, {x, 0, c}];
int = Integrate[Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}];
sc = Solve[scint == int, c] // Flatten
{c -> (3^(2/3) Pi^(1/3))/(2 2^(2/3))}

Plot[Re[sa /. sc], {x, 0, 7}, AxesLabel -> {x, u}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

If desired, the time-dependent solution can be obtained by a [do-it-yourself method of lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78564/1063) applied to

```
{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x,t],x] + D[u[x, t]^2 D[u[x, t], x], x], 
u[7, t] == 0, Integrate[u[x,t], {x, 0, 7}] == Sqrt[Pi]/2, u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]}
```

over the domain `{0, 7}`.