# Steady state solution (1D) of nonlinear dispersal equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, ecology

Now I'm interested in the equation $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Bigl(\text{sgn}(x) u \Big) +\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigl[ u^2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \Bigr] =0$$ with boundary conditions $u(-5)=u(5)=0$

Since $\text{sgn}(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, I expectd ND solve to have some problems. I tried

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{
  0 == D[Sign[x]*u[x],x] + D[u[x]^2 D[u[x], x], x],
   u[-6] == 0, u[6] == 0}
  , u, {x, -7, 7}]
```

but I can't even plot it and I think that I'm writing it in the wrong way. Could someone confirm I wrote the right snippet and show the plot I should obtain?

- I asked a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230429/nonlinear-dispersal-equation-modeling-insect-aggregation) three days ago, where the equation was the PDE $\partial_t u = \partial_x (\text{sign}(x) u) + \partial_x (u^2\partial_x u)$. The one I have above it's the **steady state** solution, and I want to compute it directly, instead of integrating in time.

Comment: "but I can't even plot it " If you can't even solve it, you won't be able to plot it of course.

Comment: @xzczd yes, but I think it's a problem of my code/Mathematica in my laptop. So I need to see at least what I should obtain

Comment: Actually, one of my concerns  is also if the problem is ill-posed. Because this could be the source of my problem. Do you obtain something reasonable with NDsolve? @xzczd

Comment: Is `u[x]==u[-x]` symmetric?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't know honestly... from a picture in the linked question it seems so. Dooes your NDsolve obtain something reasonable?

Comment: @Vefhug If yes `u[x]==const` would solve the ode!

Comment: Yes, $u(x)=0$ would be a solution. But if instead of $u^2$ there would be $\sqrt{u}$, then it seems (see figure at the end of the xzczd's post here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230429/nonlinear-dispersal-equation-modeling-insect-aggregation?noredirect=1&lq=1 ) that there's a not trivial solution, right? @UlrichNeumann

Comment: I'm talking about  $$\partial_x (\text{sign}(x) u) + \partial_x ( \sqrt{u} \partial_x u)$$ with homogeneous b.c.'s as before

Comment: The problematic part is: D[Sign[x]*u[x],x]. You can not take the derivative of "Sign" in the normal sense. It would result in a distribution, the DiracDelta. But this makes only sense inside an integral.

Comment: @DanielHuber yes, indeed I wrote a Python code following a finite element approach, (I'm newbie at Mathematica) and solving the resulting non-linear system with fixed-point iterations, but the solution explodes. I was thinking to show the steps I did, but since it's a Mathematica site, I don't know if it makes sense to show it honestly.

Comment: For instance, what is the output you obtain using a finite element method with Mathematica? @DanielHuber

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem can be solved analytically.

First we transform the equation a bit. Integrate the ODE once we obtain

```
neweq = Integrate[D[Sign[x] u[x], x] + D[u[x]^2 D[u[x], x], x], x] == c
(* Sign[x] u[x] + u[x]^2 Derivative[1][u][x] == c *)
```

Then it's not hard to notice `Sign[x] u[x] + u[x]^2 Derivative[1][u][x]` is an odd function. We can analyze it manually, but here I'll use [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) to make the post a bit more interesting:

```
(* Definition of DChange isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
DChange[Sign[x] u[x] + u[x]^2 u'[x], x == -X, x, X, u[x]] // Expand
(* -Sign[X] u[X] - u[X]^2 Derivative[1][u][X] *)
```

Thus `Sign[x] u[x] + u[x]^2 u'[x] == 0` at `x == 0`. Since `c` is a constant, we conclude `c == 0`.

Next we write it as an ODE of $x(u)$ for convenience of subsequent discussion:

```
neweqreverse = neweq /. c -> 0 /. {u[x] -> u, x -> x[u], u'[x] -> 1/x'[u]}
(* u Sign[x[u]] + u^2/Derivative[1][x][u] == 0 *)
```

Solve the ODE for $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately:

```
{eqR, eqL} = Simplify[neweqreverse, #] & /@ {x[u] > 0, x[u] < 0}
(* {u + u^2/Derivative[1][x][u] == 0, u (-1 + u/Derivative[1][x][u]) == 0} *)

solR = DSolveValue[{eqR, x[top] == 0}, x[u], u] // Simplify
(* 1/2 (top^2 - u^2) *)

solL = DSolveValue[{eqL, x[top] == 0}, x[u], u] // Simplify
(* 1/2 (-top^2 + u^2) *)
```

Notice here `top` is the value of $u(0)$.

For $u(-5)=u(5)=0$, the graphic of solutions can be obtained with e.g.

```
ParametricPlot[{#, u}, {u, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, x < 0], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]~Show~
   ParametricPlot[{#2, u}, {u, -5, 5}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, x > 0]] & @@ ({solL, solR} /. c -> 0 /. 
   Solve[solR == 5 /. c -> 0 /. u -> 0, top][[1]])
```

[image]

As we can see, there exist 2 non-trivial solutions.

BTW it's easy to notice that $u = 0$ only if $x=\pm \frac{\text{top}^2}{2}$, so b.c.s like $u(-5)=u(6)=0$ don't form a well posed problem.

### Remark

1. Solution for $m=\frac{1}{2}$ case i.e.

   ```
   D[Sign[x] u[x], x] + D[u[x]^(1/2) D[u[x], x], x] == 0
   ```

   can be discussed in the same manner. Solution for $u(-6)=u(6)=0$ when $m=\frac{1}{2}$ can be plotted with e.g.

   ```
   ParametricPlot[{#, u}, {u, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, x < 0], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]~Show~
      ParametricPlot[{#2, u}, {u, -10, 10}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x}, x > 0], 
       PlotRange -> All] & @@ ({solL, solR} /. c -> 0 /. 
      Solve[solR == 6 /. c -> 0 /. u -> 0, top][[1]])
   ```

   [image]

   As illustrated, there's only one non-trivial solution when $m=\frac{1}{2}$.
2. One can directly solve `neweq /. c -> 0` with `DSolve`. A warning will be generated then, but the results are correct.

Comment: Wow, thanks again for such an answer @xzczd Just one last thing: is it bad-posed also in case where in place of $u^2$ I have $\sqrt{u}$?  Because in your previous answer of two days your showed the same solution of the book in case $m=\frac{1}{2}$, which corresponds to $\sqrt{u}$ and the steady state case

Comment: @Vefhug Yes, see my update for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but for the csae $m=\frac{1}{2}$, I can't understand which boundary conditons you imposed. Still $u(-6)=u(6)$ right? @xzczd

Comment: @Vefhug No, it's still $u(0)=\text{top}$. Then one can deduce $u=0$ only if $x=\pm 2\sqrt{\text{top}}$.

Comment: Perfect, it's clear. The real last question ( I promise): for $u(-6)=u(6)=0$  we lose again uniquenuess and will obtain the same situation you plotted for the case $u^2$, right?

Comment: @Vefhug In short, when $m=2$ there'll always be 2 solutions for $u(\pm L)=0$, where $L>0$.

Comment: I just wanted to know about $m=\frac{1}{2}$, for $m=2$ it's clear @xzczd

Comment: @Vefhug For $m=\frac{1}{2}$, there's always only one solution for $u(\pm L)=0$ where $L>0$.

Comment: Thanks :-) @xzczd

Comment: @Vefhug Discussion for odevity has been simplified, have a look. BTW it's OK to wait for a day or even longer before accepting to see if better answer(s) come out :) .

Comment: I asked a related question here, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230896/nonlinear-system-for-chemotaxis where I am always in the biology contest