# NonLinear system for chemotaxis

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, nonlinear, finite-difference-method

I want to solve the chemotaxis mode, given by the next **non-linear** system:

It is taken from [Murray's book: equation (11.30) at pag. 408](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.725.7032&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2} -\xi_0 \partial_x \Bigl(  n \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} \Bigr)$$

$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial t} = hn - ka +  D_a \frac{\partial^2 a}{\partial x^2}$$

where $h,k,D_a,D$ are just parameters, and $D_a>D$ and the domain is $x \in [-6,6]$

I decided to take as **no flux** boundary conditions, i.e. $$\partial_x(n(-6,t))=\partial_x (a(-6,t))=0$$  $$\partial_x(n(6,t))=\partial_x (a(6,t))=0$$

and as initial conditions $$n(0,x)=e^{-x^2}$$ $$a(0,x)=\cos( \pi x)$$

Note that numerically the conditions are compatbile since the exponential is "flat". I know that analytically it's not true.

I integrated up to time $T=0.1$ with my own FEM solver (with linear finite elements) and obtain the following, using the parameters
$$D = 2 \quad D_a = 5.5 \quad  h = 0.5 \quad  k = 0.5 \quad \xi_0 = 0.2$$

[image: my solution]

I'd like to use Mathematica to check my results and to try what comes out by changing some parameters, but I can't understand how to  solve a non-linear system like the one above. Could someone show the plot I should obtain with Mathematica, and, if possible, the right code-snippet?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is what I obtain, which has the shape of Daniel answer's, which seems to be similar to his one
[image]

**EDIT:**

The pysical principle behind the model is:

*The amoebae of the slime mould Dictyostelium discoideum, with density n(x, t),
secrete a chemical attractant, cyclic-AMP, and spatial aggregations of amoebae start
to form.*  THe book says ti use **zero-flux** boundary conditions, and that's fine. But what initial conditions could I use for $n(x,t)$ and $a(x,t)$ that are physically relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the Finite Element Method, `no flux` is the default boundary condition, so there is no need to specify.  An alternative to Daniel's answer would be:

```
(* Define parameters *)
l = 6;
tend = 0.1;
parms = {d -> 2, da -> 5.5, h -> 0.5, k -> 0.5, x0 -> 0.2};
(* Create Parametric PDE operators for n and a *)
parmnop = 
  D[n[t, x], t] - d D[n[t, x], x, x] + x0 D[n[t, x] D[a[t, x], x], x];
parmaop = D[a[t, x], t] - da D[a[t, x], x, x] + k a[t, x] - h n[t, x];
(* Setup PDE System *)
pden = (parmnop == 0) /. parms;
pdea = (parmaop == 0) /. parms;
icn = n[0, x] == Exp[-x^2];
ica = a[0, x] == Cos[π x];
(* Solve System *)
{nif, aif} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pden, pdea, icn, ica}, {n, a}, {t, 0, tend}, {x, -l, 
    l}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1}}];

(* Display results *)
Manipulate[
 Plot[{nif[t, x], aif[t, x]}, {x, -l, l}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 
  tend}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, by setting `Method -> {"FiniteElement"}`, `NDSolve` uses pure FEM for solving the system, which isn't quite good for IBVP. Just check `Plot[D[aif[t,x],x]/.x->l,{t,0,tend}]`. `Method -> {MethodOfLines,SpatialDiscretization->{"FiniteElement",MeshOptions->MaxCellMeasure->0.1}}` would be a better choice.

Comment: I took the liberty to add @xzczd suggestion. It's better to use the method of lines for time dependent PDEs.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much! Actually, when I was working the answer, I was using your recommended approach.  I got over zealous trying to tighten the code.  I just eye-balled the results without a thorough check.

Comment: @user21 Cheers for the edit!

Comment: @TimLaska Tanks for your answer. Just one last point, about the physics of the system (see my last **EDIT**). I don't know what are some suitable initial conditions for $n(x,t)$ and $a(x,t)$. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Vefhug I don't have any great familiarity with the physics, but I would suspect `a` should be intrinsically positive if it represents a concentration.  You could have a look at this [presentation](https://www.jamstec.go.jp/es/jp/project/sangyou_report/H27_KEISOKU_ENGINEERING_en.pdf) to get some ideas on how it was implemented in another solver.  Perhaps something like this `icn = n[0, x] == TukeyWindow[x/11, 0.025]; ica = 
 a[0, x] == 10 TukeyWindow[x/10, 0.025] Abs[Cos[\[Pi] x]]` are similar to those provided in the link.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code. Unfortunately, at t==0.1, it does not duplicate your result. I hope I did not make a mistake.

```
eq = {D[n[x, t], t] == 
     d  D[n[x, t], {x, 2}] - c0 D[n[x, t] D[a[x, t], x], x],
    D[a[x, t], t] == h  n[x, t ] - k a[x, t] + da  D[a[x, t], {x, 2}],
    (D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> -6) == 0, (D[a[x, t], x] /. x -> -6) == 
     0, (D[n[x, t], x] /. x ->   6) == 
     0, (D[a[x, t], x] /. x ->   6) == 0,
    n[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2], a[x, 0] == Cos[Pi x]} /. {d -> 2, da -> 5.5,
     h -> 0.5, k -> 0.5, c0 -> 0.2};
sol[x_] = {n[x, 0.1], a[x, 0.1]} /. 
  NDSolve[eq, {n, a}, {t, 0, 0.1}, {x, -6, 6}][[1]]
Plot[sol[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DanielHuber. I edited my question with the actual plot I obtain. How did you impose noflux boundary conditions in your code?

Comment: @The b.c.s are `(D[n[x, t], x] /. x -> -6) == 0, (D[a[x, t], x] /. x -> -6) == 
     0, (D[n[x, t], x] /. x ->   6) == 
     0, (D[a[x, t], x] /. x ->   6) == 0`, which are straightforward translations of those b.c.s in traditional math notation. If you're having difficulty in understanding them, please check document of `D`, `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), `Rule` (`->`) by pressing the **F1** key.

Comment: You may specify no flux b.c. in different way: I used e.g: D[f[x,t],x]  /. x->6 . But you can also say: Derivative[1,0][f][6,t ] . What is clearer is up to your taste. Note also for function with only one variable you can abbreviate the first derivative by: f'[x]

Comment: @DanielHuber and xzczd, thanks for you answer/comments. I edited my question with a last point, about the physics of the system. I don't know what are some suitable initial conditions for $n(x,t)$ and $a(x,t)$.

Comment: @Vefhug Hi, I do not know enough about the real problem to give a real good answer. However, no flux boundary means, when there are no walls, that the functions at xmin and xmax stays constant. On the other hand, if you introduce position depended parameters, you can model something of a soft or hard wall and drop the condition that derivatives at the ends are zero. But I think this is more complicated than your teacher intend it to be.