# Inactive[Grad] is lost when NDSolve parses PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I encountered this when trying to solve the PDE mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230429/1871). I've transformed the equation to the following:

```
With[{u = u[x, t]}, 
 neweq = D[u, t] == Inactive[Div][{{u^2}}.Inactive[Grad][u, {x}], {x}] + 
                    {1}.Inactive[Grad][Sign[x] u, {x}]]
```

This is the formal PDE for `FiniteElement` method as far as I can tell, but it doesn't lead to the correct solution. After checking with [`GetInactivePDE`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871), I found the `Inactive[Grad][Sign[x] u, {x}]]` term is simply lost in parsing stage:

```
(* Definition of GetInactivePDE isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
showFormalPDE[a__] := 
  Module[{state}, {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[a];
   GetInactivePDE[state["FiniteElementData"]@"PDECoefficientData", 
      state@"VariableData"] == 0 // Thread];

{bc, ic} = {{u[-7, t] == 0, u[7, t] == 0}, u[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2]};
showFormalPDE[{neweq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, -7, 7}]
(* {Inactive[Div][-{{u[x]^2}} . Inactive[Grad][u[t, x], {x}], {x}] + 
    Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] == 0} *)
```

Is this a bug? Or separate `Inactive[Grad][……]` term in PDE is not allowed at the moment?

Tested on *v12.1.1*.

---

Just a simpler sample reflecting the underlying issue:

```
eq = D[u[x, t], t] == Inactive[Grad][aaaa[x], {x}];
ic = u[x, 0] == 0;
showFormalPDE[{eq, ic}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
(* {Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] == 0} *)
```

Comment: There is no right definition of inactive form of equation for FEM. This is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. You can not have `Inactive[Grad][Sign[x] u[x], {x}]` you can only have `Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}]` the rest needs to go into some coefficient.

Comment: Oh, I see… but I'd argue that a warning should be generated in this case.

Comment: Yes, a warning probably would be good. The problem is when I first wrote that parser I wrote it in a way that would look at the entire equation and then extract the components it recognizes. However, it does not 'subtract' what it recognizes from the argument given and in the end I have no knowledge of what did not get parsed. Trust me I would not do it this way again, but re-writing the parser would be quite a thing. Maybe something in the future. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is not clear why we need inactive form of equation for FEM. And also we don't know what is inactive form in every case.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Have a look at the documentation. The main point of `Inactive` is to prevent premature evaluation - that's necessary for a variety of reasons, have a look [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#588198981), [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1585211872) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1216827418).

Comment: @user21 I read documentation during last several years, but I don't understand why we need inactive form at all. Is it connected with some algorithm implemented in `NDSolve`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, it's not clear to me what information you are looking for regarding `Inactive` that is not on the above pages. Can you clarify? Give me a specific sentence or section that you do not understand.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. Suppose we have an `equation`  containing `D, Derivative, Div, Grad, Curl, Laplacian`. We can made it inactive simply used `Inactivate[equation, D| Derivative| Div| Grad| Curl| Laplacian] `. This can be done automatically without users efforts.  Then why we doing this every time?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, This could only be done for functions with `Attribute` `HoldFirst` or `HoldAll`. `NDSolve` and `NDEigensystem` are not.

Comment: @user21 What do you mean? Can we use some automatic option to convert any equation in a form suitable for FEM?  It looks like unsolved problem in Wolfram language. :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev, `NDSolve[Laplancian[u[x],{x}],...]` can not automatically be converted to `NDSolve[Inactive[Laplacian][u[x],{x}],...]`

Comment: @user21 Ok! I see your point. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I have used the content of this conversation to make another example to further explain the need of `Inactive`.