# Time dependent Schrödinger equation in 2D

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, modeling, finite-difference-method

I have the following Schrödinger equation in $2D$:

\begin{cases}
\partial_t \Psi(x,t) = V(x,t) \Psi(x,t) \quad x \in [-10,10]^2\\
\Psi(x,0)=\exp( \frac{1}{2} (-x^2+y^2))
\end{cases}

where the potential $V(x,t)=\mathbb{i} \Bigl( \frac{1}{2} \Delta - (x^2+y^2) - \sin^2(t) (x+y) \Bigr)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. I need the solution at time $T=1$.

Using second order finite differences, I obtain the following plot, **plotting** $|U|$ at $T=1$:[image]

with the following colormap

[image]

I'd like to use Mathematica to check my results and to try what comes out by changing some parameters, but I don't know how to solve it properly. Could someone show the plot of the surface I should obtain with Mathematica, and, if possible, the right code-snippet?

**EDIT:**

I had a different initial data, now my plot seems to agree with the on of Henrik

[image]

Comment: It looks like you try to reproduce some results from our paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/adts.201900011 ?

Comment: Honestly not, I took it from https://sci-hub.st/10.1137/S1064827595295337, pg.19 @AlexTrounev

Comment: I see that you took Example 7.3 extended on 2D. But your example has no stiffness.

Comment: @AlexTrounev sorry. why does it have no stiffness?

Comment: If we put like in the paper κ = 10 and µ = 100 then  we get at `t=1` numerical solution with several pikes and message from the system. In this case method of lines is preferable.

Comment: @AlexTrounev why is it preferable? THe smoothness of the solution is bad in that case

Comment: It can be managed by choice of the number of points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following should do. It employ the finite element method.

```
Ω =   DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}], MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.5)];
sol = NDSolveValue[
   {
    D[Ψ[x, y, t], t] == I/2 Laplacian[Ψ[x, y, t], {x, y}] - I ((x^2 + y^2) + (x + y) Sin[t]^2) Ψ[x, y, t], 
    DirichletCondition[Ψ[x, y, t] == 0, True],
    Ψ[x, y, 0] == Exp[-1/2 (x^2 + y^2)]
    },
   Ψ,
   {t, 0, 1},
   {x, y} ∈ Ω
   ];
Plot3D[Abs[sol[x, y, 1]], {x, y} ∈ Ω, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "|Ψ|"}]
```

[image]

Looks a bit different from OP's solution, but that could be to a copying error... Anyways, this shows roughly how the PDE can be solved.

For further details (in particular on how to increase the accuracy of the solution), please refer to the documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html).

[image]

Finding the maximum:

```
NMaximize[{Abs[sol[x, y, 1]], -10 <= x <= 10, -10 <= y <= 10}, {x, y}]

{1.38754, {x -> -0.0632606, y -> -0.0637582}}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'm trying to plot it but it doesn't  show anything. Does Mathemtica plots something to you? If so, could you please add it, so that I can accept your answer? @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: Hm. What is you version of _Mathematica_? I used `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve` because it returns a function an not a rule. But `NDSolveValue` was only added quite recently... Also there has quite some progress in _Mathematica's_ capabilities, so the version number might be critical.

Comment: @Vefhug As shown by Henrik, it's quite straightforward to solve the problem in _Mathematica_, why do you think [it's too hard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230429/nonlinear-dispersal-equation-modeling-insect-aggregation/230431?noredirect=1#comment586825_230431)?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I had problems with the imaginary unit. Btw, your solution is not the correct one because you have `I (x + y) Sin[t]^2` instead of `-I (x + y) Sin[t]^2`. Could you just plot it, so that I can accept your answer with the correct graph?

Comment: @Vefhug This is the correct one, don't miss the pair of parentheses.

Comment: @xzczd my bad, you're absolutely right. I also found the mistake of my FD based solution: I was using a slightly different initial data. Now the plots should agree

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What is the maximum value you obtain with your version of Mathematica? I got  that the maximum value is at $(0,0)$  and is $1.124$

Comment: On the grid above, I got $1.29017$ as maximum at position $(x ,y) =  (-0.181918, -0.0153922)$, but the discretization is rather coarse. On a grid with double the resolution (i.e., with `MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.25)`), I got $1.29844$ as maximum at position $(x ,y) =  (-0.181918,  -0.0153922)$.

Comment: Better to remove the `∈ Ω` in `NMaximize`, then there's no warning and the output is `{1.44277, {x -> 0.127249, y -> 0.127515}}`.

Comment: It seems that the maximum depends a bit too much on the grid resolution, right? @HenrikSchumacher

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You have a typo in equation with `I` compare to paper, OP and xzczd.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Keen eye! Thank you.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Ok! Now it looks better (+1).

Answer (score 7):

`FiniteElement` isn't necessary for this problem. The old good `TensorProductGrid` handles the problem quite well:

```
system = With[{Ψ = Ψ[x, y, t]}, 
          {D[Ψ, t] == I (Laplacian[Ψ, {x, y}]/2 - ((x^2 + y^2) + Sin[t]^2 (x + y)) Ψ),
           Ψ == 0 /. {{x -> -10}, {x -> 10}, {y -> -10}, {y -> 10}},
           Ψ == Exp[-1/2 (x^2 + y^2)] /. t -> 0}];

sol = NDSolveValue[system, Ψ, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];

Plot3D[Abs@sol[x, y, 1], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]

NMaximize[Abs[sol[x, y, 1]], {x, y}]   
(* {1.4014, {x -> -0.0593488, y -> -0.0593488}} *)
```

Test passes in *v12.1.1*.

---

Futher tests show *v9.0.1* and *v8.0.4* have difficulty in solving the system  with defaullt setting, so this turns out to be another example indicating `NDSolve` is improved silently these years. Nevertheless, with the magic of `Pseudospectral`, we can still solve the problem in *v8* and *v9*:

```
If[$VersionNumber < 9, Laplacian = D[#, x, x] + D[#, y, y] &;
  NDSolveValue = #2 /. First@NDSolve[##] &];

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

system = With[{Ψ = Ψ[x, y, t]}, 
          {D[Ψ, t] == I (Laplacian[Ψ, {x, y}]/2 - ((x^2 + y^2) + Sin[t]^2 (x + y)) Ψ),
           Ψ == 0 /. {{x -> -10}, {x -> 10}, {y -> -10}, {y -> 10}},
           Ψ == Exp[-1/2 (x^2 + y^2)] /. t -> 0}];

sol = NDSolveValue[system, Ψ, {t, 0, 1}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Method -> mol[55]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* v8.0.4: {178.4673377, Null} *)
(* v9.0.1: {40.305892, Null} *)

FindMaximum[Abs@sol[x, y, 1], {x, y}]
(* v8.0.4: {1.38975, {x -> -0.0438577, y -> -0.0438577}} *)
(* v9.0.1: lstol warning, {1.38918, {x -> -0.0439239, y -> -0.043924}} *)
```

`NMaximize` isn't used to find the maximum because it spits out a `` Experimental`NumericalFunction[…] `` as output in *v8* and *v9*, which is obviously a (now fixed) bug.

Comment: Thanks @xzczd. Tensor product is a FD implementation?

Comment: @Vefhug FD Yes. (But notice `TensorProductGrid` is used only for spatial dimension i.e. `x` and `y` direction in this problem. It's ODE solver that's used in `t` direction. )

Comment: Sure, so it's the classical method of lines :) @xzczd

Answer (score 4):

You can simply solve this equation using NDSolve.

Note, I rewrote your equation a bit more towards standard form.

```
V[x_, y_, t_] := (x^2 + y^2 +  Sin[t]^2 (x + y));
eq = {I  Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, 
      t] == -Laplacian[f[x, y, t], {x, y}]/2 + V[x, y, t] f[x, y, t], 
   f[x, y, 0] == Exp[-1/2 (x^2 + y^2)], 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, t] == 0, True]};
sol = NDSolve[eq, f, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 1}]

fu[x_, y_] = Abs@f[x, y, 1] /. sol;
Plot3D[fu[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: @DanielHubner thanks. What is the maximum of $|\Psi|$? Just to see if it's identycal to mine

Comment: Hi, I get a max of Abs[f[0,0]] = 1.37179

Comment: @DanielHubner I obtain the max as $(0,0)$ and it is $1.124$. Is it normal to have so large errors in two dimensional plots?

Comment: Certainly no. But, I gave you the absolute value of f, not f.Conjugate[f] what is more standard. Could it be that your value comes from Psi^2?