# Kolmogorov backward PDE with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, finance, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to solve numerically Kolmogorov backward PDE with boundary conditions:

```
\[Sigma] = 0.1; \[Mu] = 0.05; k = 1; T = 1; 
sol = NDSolve[{D[p[a, t], t] + (1/2)*\[Sigma]^2*a^2*D[p[a, t], a, a] + \[Mu]*a*D[p[a, t], a] == 0, 
    p[k, t] == 1, p[a, T] == 0}, p, {a, 1, 10}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

But it first complains about the boundary conditions (which in a way I can understand because of the `p[1,1]` point). But more importantly the outputted solution is nonsensical:

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[p[a, t] /. sol], {a, 1, 10}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

The physical problem I am trying to solve is the following: what is the probability of default of a firm with debt `k` and assets given by ito process (variable `a`). If `a=k` then the firm has defaulted, hence the first boundary condition. If `a>k` and `t=T` (`T` is the final point) then the probability of default is zero (no time left). This makes perfect sense to me, but something is not right mathematically (or programmatically). Any ideas?

**Update**

Following xzczd's advice in the comments, I added a condition at infinity (`a=10`). I also introduced `UnitStep` function to make boundary conditions consistent and stop the warning.

```
\[Sigma] = 0.1; \[Mu] = 0.05; k = 1; T = 1; 
sol = NDSolve[{D[p[a, t], t] + (1/2)*\[Sigma]^2*a^2*D[p[a, t], a, a] + \[Mu]*a*D[p[a, t], a] == 0, 
    p[k, t] == 1, p[a, T] == UnitStep[k - a], p[10*k, t] == 0}, p, {a, 1, 3}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: You haven't set enough b.c., which leads to `bcart` warning. This is a serious problem. Check the following for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871

Comment: But the initial boundary conditions I imposed seem to be sufficient, from mathematical standpoint, for a parabolic PDE as backward Kolmogorov equation is. I don't see any logical issue with them.

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, what's not sufficient is boundary condition (b.c.). You're probably solving the problem in a semi-infinite domain, and you need one more b.c. approximating b.c. at infinity, which is often given implicitly when analytically solving the problem. For more info you may check the tag [boundary-condition-at-infinity].